# Steps to trouble shoot SSL

Tags: java, ssl

I am trying to trouble shoot a two way SSL handshake mechanism. I get an error

`Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

This indicates that one of my keystore or my truststore files does not have the appropriate entries. I know the way to trouble shoot this is to go to the server's truststore do the keytool list check the signing authorities and come to the client's key/truststore and verify this.

Can someone list these steps clearly (with the appropriate commands) please? Googling is not leading me anywhere. I just need a list of steps of "How can I confirm that Client X can talk to Server Y with two way SSL using Cert Z"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The SunCertPathBuilderException exception is thrown whenever there the certificate validator fails to establish a chain between the certificate and a root certificate.

The easiest way to confirm that the certificate validates is to use a graphical tool like

- [Keyman](http://www.alphaworks.ibm.com/tech/keyman), or
- [KeyTool IUI](https://keytool-iui-for-windows.apponic.com/)

The above tools are recommended since the exception is usually thrown in the absence of a root certificate.

If you want to examine what certificates are getting exchanged, it is better to switch on the [ssl debug flag](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html) on the JVM node where the validation is failing.

Another option is to use a network traffic capture utility like [Ethereal](http://www.ethereal.com/) or [Microsoft Netmon](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=103158) to obtain a dump of the traffic containing the certificate exchanges.

PS: Are you using the right keystore in the first place? I remember doing the same mistake many moons ago...

Comment: Hi Vineet,
I have access to the certificates. I want to know what entries do I compare ? There is just so much information in the certificate. Is there a good link on HOW TO READ a certificate?

Comment: Are you using the right keystore in the first place? 
How can I determine this ? I know I have to compare something in the bin/keytool output but what is it?

Comment: The keystore for a JVM is normally set at startup, although you can change this later using a System.setProperty() call. Therefore, if your JRE's keystore is different from the one you are using to store the certificates, you will see this exception especially when the JRE's keystore does not have the intermediate or trusted CA certs.

Comment: By the way, if you want to validate the certificate chain, use KeyTool IUI. Load the keystore using the tool, and it should present you with the certificates in it; you can view the certificate chain by choosing an appropriate 'key entry'. Using KeyTool IUI you will be able to verify if the cert validates at the sender. The recipient is where the error is encountered, and you need to look for corresponding intermediate and root certs at the recipient, as you have found in the sender.