# Received fatal alert: handshake_failure through SSLHandshakeException

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, sslhandshakeexception

I have a problem with authorized SSL connection. I have created Struts Action that connects to external server with Client Authorized SSL certificate. In my Action I am trying to send some data to bank server but without any luck, because I have as a result from server the following error:

```
error: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

My Method from my Action class that sends data to server

```
//Getting external IP from host
    URL whatismyip = new URL("http://automation.whatismyip.com/n09230945.asp");
    BufferedReader inIP = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(whatismyip.openStream()));

    String IPStr = inIP.readLine(); //IP as a String

    Merchant merchant;

    System.out.println("amount: " + amount + ", currency: " + currency + ", clientIp: " + IPStr + ", description: " + description);

    try {

        merchant = new Merchant(context.getRealPath("/") + "merchant.properties");

    } catch (ConfigurationException e) {

        Logger.getLogger(HomeAction.class.getName()).log(Level.INFO, "message", e);
        System.err.println("error: " + e.getMessage());
        return ERROR;
    }

    String result = merchant.sendTransData(amount, currency, IPStr, description);

    System.out.println("result: " + result);

    return SUCCESS;
```

My merchant.properties file:

```
bank.server.url=https://-servernameandport-/
https.cipher=-cipher-

keystore.file=-key-.jks
keystore.type=JKS
keystore.password=-password-
ecomm.server.version=2.0

encoding.source=UTF-8
encoding.native=UTF-8
```

For the first time I thought this is a certificate problem, I converted it from .pfx to .jks, but I have the same error, with no changes.

Comment: did you add the server's ssl cert to your truststore?

Comment: i'll assume that your app is using the java default truststore. The default truststore is <java-home>/lib/security/cacerts. open the server's url with your browser and download all the ssl certs; including any chain/intermediate certs. then add all these certs to the truststore.

Comment: I cannot open the url in the browser, because of client authentication certificate, I can send to this link only specific parameters that I get from clients.

Comment: just open the url. ignore all errors that you see on your browser. when you access the url, you should see a padlock icon on the address bar of your browser. click on that and download the server's ssl cert.

Comment: I should, but there isn't any padlock icon at all :(, hmm, when I open up link in my browser, it's shows me the following error, the same as in netbeans: "SSL peer was unable to negotiate an acceptable set of security parameters.

(Error code: ssl_error_handshake_failure_alert)"

Comment: Please post the entire exception and stack trace.

Comment: In my case was a incompatibility with ibm jvm... after switch to oracle jvm, the problema was solved.

Comment: I received this error because of incompatible cipher suites used by the client.  By updating my `local_policy` and `US_export_policy` jars in my JDK's `security` folder with the ones provided in the [Java Cryptography Extension](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html), I was able to complete the handshake successfully.

Comment: TLDR: Add `-Djavax.net.debug=all` to JVM args, and look for `javax.net.ssl|ERROR|`. Likely, you will see `unable to find valid certification path to requested target`.

Comment: One possible reason of `SSLHandshakeException` is a missing JDK module: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55439599/sslhandshakeexception-with-jlink-created-runtime

Answer (score 310, accepted):

The handshake failure could have occurred due to various reasons:

- Incompatible cipher suites in use by the client and the server. This would require the client to use (or enable) a cipher suite that is supported by the server.
- Incompatible versions of SSL in use (the server might accept only TLS v1, while the client is capable of only using SSL v3). Again, the client might have to ensure that it uses a compatible version of the SSL/TLS protocol.
- Incomplete trust path for the server certificate; the server's certificate is probably not trusted by the client. This would usually result in a more verbose error, but it is quite possible. Usually the fix is to import the server's CA certificate into the client's trust store.
- The cerificate is issued for a different domain. Again, this would have resulted in a more verbose message, but I'll state the fix here in case this is the cause. The resolution in this case would be get the server (it does not appear to be yours) to use the correct certificate.

Since, the underlying failure cannot be pinpointed, it is better to switch on the  [`-Djavax.net.debug=all`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html) flag to enable debugging of the SSL connection established. With the debug switched on, you can pinpoint what activity in the handshake has failed.

**Update**

Based on the details now available, it appears that the problem is due to an incomplete certificate trust path between the certificate issued to the server, and a root CA. In most cases, this is because the root CA's certificate is absent in the trust store, leading to the situation where a certificate trust path cannot exist; the certificate is essentially untrusted by the client. Browsers can present a warning so that users may ignore this, but the same is not the case for SSL clients (like the [HttpsURLConnection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html) class, or any HTTP Client library like Apache [HttpComponents Client](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html)).

Most these client classes/libraries would rely on the trust store used by the JVM for certificate validation. In most cases, this will be the `cacerts` file in the JRE_HOME/lib/security directory. If the location of the trust store has been specified using the JVM system property `javax.net.ssl.trustStore`, then the store in that path is usually the one used by the client library. If you are in doubt, take a look at your `Merchant` class, and figure out the class/library it is using to make the connection.

Adding the server's certificate issuing CA to this trust store ought to resolve the problem. You can refer to my [answer on a related question on getting tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492762/steps-to-trouble-shoot-ssl) for this purpose, but the [Java keytool utility](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html) is sufficient for this purpose.

***Warning***: The trust store is essentially the list of all CAs that you trust. If you put in an certificate that does not belong to a CA that you do not trust, then SSL/TLS connections to sites having certificates issued by that entity can be decrypted if the private key is available.

**Update #2: Understanding the output of the JSSE trace**

The keystore and the truststores used by the JVM are usually listed at the very beginning, somewhat like the following:

```
keyStore is : 
keyStore type is : jks
keyStore provider is : 
init keystore
init keymanager of type SunX509
trustStore is: C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\jre\lib\security\cacerts
trustStore type is : jks
trustStore provider is :
```

If the wrong truststore is used, then you'll need to re-import the server's certificate to the right one, or reconfigure the server to use the one listed (not recommended if you have multiple JVMs, and all of them are used for different needs).

If you want to verify if the list of trust certs contains the required certs, then there is a section for the same, that starts as:

```
adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=blah, O=blah, C=blah
  Issuer:  CN=biggerblah, O=biggerblah, C=biggerblah
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: yadda
  Valid from SomeDate until SomeDate
```

You'll need to look for if the server's CA is a subject.

The handshake process will have a few salient entries (you'll need to know SSL to understand them in detail, but for the purpose of debugging the current problem, it will suffice to know that a handshake_failure is usually reported in the ServerHello.

**1. ClientHello**

A series of entries will be reported when the connection is being initialized. The first message sent by the client in a SSL/TLS connection setup is the ClientHello message, usually reported in the logs as:

```
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1291302508 bytes = { some byte array }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
***
```

Note the cipher suites used. This *might have to agree* with the entry in your merchant.properties file, for the same convention might be employed by the bank's library. If the convention used is different, there is no cause of worry, for the ServerHello will state so, if the cipher suite is incompatible.

**2. ServerHello**

The server responds with a ServerHello, that will indicate if the connection setup can proceed. Entries in the logs are usually of the following type:

```
*** ServerHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1291302499 bytes = { some byte array}
Cipher Suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Compression Method: 0
***
```

Note the cipher suite that it has chosen; this is best suite available to both the server and the client. Usually the cipher suite is not specified if there is an error. The certificate of the server (and optionally the entire chain) is sent by the server, and would be found in the entries as:

```
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=server, O=server's org, L=server's location, ST =Server's state, C=Server's country
  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = some identifer

.... the rest of the certificate
***
```

If the verification of the certificate has succeeded, you'll find an entry similar to:

```
Found trusted certificate:
[
[
  Version: V1
  Subject: OU=Server's CA, O="Server's CA's company name", C=CA's country
  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = some identifier
```

One of the above steps would not have succeeded, resulting in the handshake_failure, for the handshake is typically complete at this stage (not really, but the subsequent stages of the handshake typically do not cause a handshake failure). You'll need to figure out which step has failed, and post the appropriate message as an update to the question (unless you've already understood the message, and you know what to do to resolve it).

Comment: Please post whatever you've got, if you can, so that I could update the answer with a more specific one.

Comment: Ok Vineet, I cannot figure out how to deal with it, I am already exhausted. I found a way to check the server URL with openssl "openssl s_client -connect servername:4402", and look what I got: http://img225.imageshack.us/img225/8999/screenshoturr.png

Comment: @hoss, it looks like the certificate of the server was issued by an entity that is not present in the trust store used by OpenSSL, and also possibly not present in the trust store used by *your server* (the client), when it connects to the server. In that case, you'll need to import the certificate of the CA that issued the certificate (***and not the server***) into your client's (OpenSSL/your server) trust store.

Comment: @hoss, this is essentially point 3 in my above answer. I'll edit my answer to resolve this more specifically.

Comment: Thanks Vineet for help, I still don't figured out how to manage this weird exception, I will set your answer as accepted, maybe I can find a way out at Mr. Google, I'm already exhausted.

Comment: @hoss, Did you manage to get any information when using "-Djavax.net.debug=all" ?

Comment: I already tried to understand how it works, but I did not understand, I'm new to SSL, and I don't know where to start. I have generated the key from the bank's website yesterday, but don't know if it is correctly generated or not, maybe it's all because of this.

Comment: P.S. My Merchant class is from bank's library, and it's already compiled, I cannot view the source

Comment: @hoss, you might want to check the documentation of that library to see if the merchant.properties file supports specifying a trust store, or whether it takes the system trust store.

Comment: Also, you can decompile Java code. Although in this case, I think it is better not to do so, unless you are allowed to do that for the sake of interoperability.

Comment: There is nothing about trust store (in documentation)

Comment: Well, may be it is relying on cacerts. But you can determine this only if you understand the output of the network debug. If you want to check this, you'll need to use the `keytool -list -v -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts` command to print out the contents. Then verify if the certificates in cacerts match the CA of the bank's certificate.

Comment: keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: /jre/lib/security/cacerts

Comment: You need to point to the cacerts file that is used by the JRE of your application server.

Comment: It asked me for a password, I don't know what password to write

Comment: The default is usually `changeit`. Unless it was changed.

Comment: Ok, it shows a list of certificates, how to verifiy if CA coresponds?

Comment: Open the server's certificate, and verify it's signer/issuer is present in the list. Chance are that it is not there, and that's why you are getting the error.

Comment: Aha, Issuer from my certificate isn't in the list, now how to deal? :(

Comment: You'll need to add the issuer's certificate to cacerts. Use keytool if you are comfortable, or the tool mentioned in the other page (that I linked above) - KeyTool IUI.

Comment: I need to convert it to .cer format type? because keytool says that this certificare isn't an X.509 type, but when I open it in KeyTool IUI it says that Cert Type is X.509. Sorry for bothering you

Comment: I think keytool does not accept PEM style certificates, while KeyTool IUI can. You can use Keytool IUI to update the cacerts file, therefore.

Comment: Ok, terminal says: "Certificate was added to keystore", but still getting this "handshake_failure".

Comment: I think you need to restart your server. The trusted certificate list is loaded on startup.

Comment: I would suggest looking at the logs (again! for the ssl debug), but if you haven't understood it's contents, I'll try and post the important bits to look for.

Comment: @hoss, well take a look at my updated answer. Hopefully you'll find something interesting.

Comment: @ Vineet is it possible to enable JSSE trace using soapUI?

Comment: @Thomas, I'm not sure. Maybe it would be necessary to add the debug flags in the shell script used to start soapUI. This applies only if soapUI does not create a new JVM to issue HTTP requests.

Comment: @ Vineet I've added debugging to the java options in the startup script. My certificates are fine, but the whole story ends with LogList Updater for soapUI log, RECV TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure %% Invalidated:  [Session-1, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5] 11:40:57,574 ERROR [WsdlSubmit] Exception in request: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
11:40:57,574 ERROR [SoapUI] An error occured [Received fatal alert: handshake_failure], see error log for details. Using Java 1.6.0_31 It's working with other systems, but this one.

Comment: @ Vineet BTW the problem occurs only when our partner enables the validation of the SSL certificate... In the trace no errors whatsoever. Found trusted certificate: etc. But the bottom line is a handshake_failure...

Comment: very nice answer... but all these are ok in my handshake failure but still i have the failure. could you have a look at my similar question?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21704989/sslhandshakeexception-received-fatal-alert-handshake-failure-followup

Comment: i had this 'Incompatible versions of SSL in use (the server might accept only TLS v1, while the client is capable of only using SSL v3). Again, the client might have to ensure that it uses a compatible version of the SSL/TLS protocol.' so +1 for your answer :)

Comment: Should the certificate in "Certificate chain"  after  "ServerHello, TLSv1" be present in the client truststore? I was given a Keystore.jks file by the server which had couple of certificates (which I stored them in client truststore) but did not contain the one which follows after "ServerHello, TLSv1" is that the reason I am getting SSLHandshakeException.

Comment: To add to the list of possible reasons: the case we had today was Java 6 using a "SSLv2Hello" during a TLSv1 handshake. This seems to be an old workaround for servers only using SSL but not TLS. This can now cause a handshake_failure since the roles are reversed and some servers only accept TLS but not SSL. The solution to this is not allowing the "SSLv2Hello" protocol with  -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1,SSLv3  or something like that.

Comment: Most of the failures referred to at the start of this answer have their own alerts. The sentence starting 'if you put in a private key' has one too many 'not's, and 'if the private key is available' is meaningless. The server has to have its own private key, otherwise it can't send the certificate, and nobody else can decrypt the connection even if they do have the private key, unless they are mounting a MITM attack and impersonating the server. There is nothing in the TOS RFCs that says the server has to choose the best common cipher suite.

Comment: Your `-Djavax.net.debug=all` suggestion saved me a ton of headache. Thanks!

Comment: wow. this answer really explains a lot on how SSL handshakes work. Learnt something new today which will remain useful forever !

Answer (score 26):

The handshake failure could be a buggy TLSv1 protocol implementation.

In our case this helped with java 7:

```
java -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1
```

The jvm will negotiate in this order. The servers with the latest update will do 1.2, the buggy ones will go down to v1 and that works with the similar v1 in java 7.

Comment: This helped me. There was my ClientHello, but no server, the end was quite abrupt. This fixed it for me on Java 7. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 22):

Installing Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength ([for JDK7](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html) | [for JDK8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html)) might fix this bug. Unzip the file and follow the readme to install it.

Answer (score 18):

This can also happend when the client needs to present a certificate. After the server lists the certificate chain, the following can happen:

**3. Certificate Request**
The server will issue a certificate request from the client. The request will list all of the certificates the server accepts.

```
*** CertificateRequest
Cert Types: RSA
Cert Authorities:
<CN=blah, OU=blah, O=blah, L=blah, ST=blah, C=blah>
<CN=yadda, DC=yadda, DC=yadda>
<CN=moreblah, OU=moreblah, O=moreblah, C=moreblah>
<CN=moreyada, OU=moreyada, O=moreyada, C=moreyada>
... the rest of the request
*** ServerHelloDone
```

**4. Client Certificate Chain**
This is the certificate the client is sending to the server.

```
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: EMAILADDRESS=client's email, CN=client, OU=client's ou, O=client's Org, L=client's location, ST=client's state, C=client's Country
  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5
  ... the rest of the certificate
*** ClientKeyExchange, RSA PreMasterSecret, TLSv1    
... key exchange info
```

If there isn't a certificate in the chain and the server requires one, you'll get the handshake error here. A likely cause is the path to your certificate wasn't found.

**5. Certificate Verify**
The client asks the server to verify the certificate

```
*** CertificateVerify
... payload of verify check
```

This step will only happen if you are sending a certificate.

**6. Finished**
The server will respond with a verify response

```
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 345, ... }
```

Comment: in my case it seems all the steps are fine but still get the handshake error.

Comment: very nice answer... but all these are ok in my handshake failure but still i have the failure. could you have a look at my similar question?

Comment: Failure to present a client certificate is not any kind of an error in TLS. If the server requires a client certificate and one isn't presented, it will close the connection.

Comment: @EJP that's true it's not an error in TLS however the failed connection appears as an error in the Java Code.

Comment: @Brig But not as an alert, which is what this answer says, and what the question is about.

Answer (score 18):

I don't think this solves the problem to the first questioner, but for googlers coming here for answers:

---

On update 51, java 1.8 prohibited[1] RC4 ciphers by default, as we can see on the Release Notes page:

> Bug Fix: **Prohibit RC4 cipher suites**
>
> RC4 is now considered as a compromised cipher.
>
> RC4 cipher suites have been removed from both client and server default enabled cipher suite list in Oracle JSSE implementation. These cipher suites can still be enabled by `SSLEngine.setEnabledCipherSuites()` and `SSLSocket.setEnabledCipherSuites()` methods. See JDK-8077109 (not public).

If your server has a strong preference for this cipher (or use only this cipher) this can trigger a `handshake_failure` on java.

You can test connecting to the server enabling RC4 ciphers (first, try without `enabled` argument to see if triggers a `handshake_failure`, then set `enabled`:

```
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import java.io.*;

import java.util.Arrays;

/** Establish a SSL connection to a host and port, writes a byte and
 * prints the response. See
 * http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Connecting+to+SSL+services
 */
public class SSLRC4Poke {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] cyphers;
        if (args.length < 2) {
            System.out.println("Usage: "+SSLRC4Poke.class.getName()+" <host> <port> enable");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        try {
            SSLSocketFactory sslsocketfactory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
            SSLSocket sslsocket = (SSLSocket) sslsocketfactory.createSocket(args[0], Integer.parseInt(args[1]));
        
            cyphers = sslsocketfactory.getSupportedCipherSuites();
            if (args.length ==3){
                sslsocket.setEnabledCipherSuites(new String[]{
                    "SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5",
                    "SSL_DH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_MD5",
                    "SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5",
                    "SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5",
                    "SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA",
                    "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA",
                    "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA",
                    "TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA",
                    "TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA",
                    "TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_SHA",
                    "TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5",
                    "TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_SHA",
                    "TLS_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_MD5",
                    "TLS_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_SHA"
                });     
            }

            InputStream in = sslsocket.getInputStream();
            OutputStream out = sslsocket.getOutputStream();

            // Write a test byte to get a reaction :)
            out.write(1);

            while (in.available() > 0) {
                System.out.print(in.read());
            }
            System.out.println("Successfully connected");

        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

1 - https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/release_changes.xml

Answer (score 14):

I have this error while I tried to use JDK 1.7.
When I upgraded my JDK to jdk1.8.0_66 all started to work fine.

So the simplest solution for this problem could be - **upgrade your JDK** and it could start to work well.

Comment: Nice. Simplest solution is to upgrade JDK? :D Do you know how complicated that can be depending on the environment where that is being done? Suppose Amazon ran JDK 7 and would now need to upgrade to JDK 8 suddenly... Nice!

Comment: A simple minor version upgrade resolved this issue for me.. from JDK 11.0.1 to 11.0.6

Comment: Indeed the simplest solution---I had to replace jre-1.8.0-openjdk with jre-1.8.0-oracle.

Comment: I had the same problem and it was solved when I upgraded from JDK 1.7.0_09 to JDK 1.8.0_333. Something changed in the server I was connected to that made incompatible the SSL connection with JDK 1.7. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

In my case, cert is imported, error remains, solved this by adding `System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,SSLv3");` before connect

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you're using the proper SSL/TLS protocols, properly configured your `keyStore` and `trustStore`, and confirmed that there doesn't exist any issues with the certificates themselves, you may need to [strengthen your security algorithms](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/diagnosing_tls_ssl_and_https).

As mentioned in [Vineet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6353956/3813155), one possible reason you receive this error is due to incompatible cipher suites being used. By updating my `local_policy` and `US_export_policy` jars in my JDK's `security` folder with the ones provided in the [Java Cryptography Extension (JCE)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html), I was able to complete the handshake successfully.

Comment: Updating local_policy jar fixed issue for me.

Answer (score 4):

I found an HTTPS server which failed in this way if my Java client process was configured with

```
-Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false
```

The connection failed with `handshake_failure` after the `ServerHello` had finished successfully but before the data stream started.

There was no clear error message that identified the problem, the error just looked like

```
main, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
main, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
%% Invalidated:  [Session-3, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384]
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

I isolated the issue by trying with and without the "`-Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false`" option

Comment: I am getting the same error while connecting to GDAX sandbox, any solutions for this?

Comment: The solution is to either enable SNI (remove the option) or ask the remote server administrator to enable connections without SNI support.

Answer (score 3):

I meet the same problem today with OkHttp client to GET a https based url. It was **caused by Https protocol version and Cipher method mismatch between server side and client side**.

1) check your website https Protocol version and Cipher method.

`openssl>s_client -connect your_website.com:443 -showcerts`

You will get many detail info, the key info is listed as follows:

```
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : RC4-SHA
```

2) config your http client, for example, in [OkHttp client](https://github.com/square/okhttp) case:

```
@Test()
public void testHttpsByOkHttp() {
    ConnectionSpec spec = new ConnectionSpec.Builder(ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS)
            .tlsVersions(TlsVersion.TLS_1_0) //protocol version
            .cipherSuites(
                    CipherSuite.TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, //cipher method
                    CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                    CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                    CipherSuite.TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256)
            .build();

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    client.setConnectionSpecs(Collections.singletonList(spec));
    Request request = new Request.Builder().url("https://your_website.com/").build();
    try {
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        if(response.isSuccessful()){
            logger.debug("result= {}", response.body().string());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This will get what we want.

Answer (score 2):

I am using com.google.api http client.  When I communicate with an internal company site, I got this problem when I mistakenly used https, instead of http.

```
main, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
main, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
main, IOException in getSession():  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
main, called close()
main, called closeInternal(true)
262 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection  - Connection shut down
main, called close()
main, called closeInternal(true)
263 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager  - Released connection is not reusable.
263 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute  - Releasing connection [HttpRoute[{s}->https://<I-replaced>]][null]
263 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute  - Notifying no-one, there are no waiting threads
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:431)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:128)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:339)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:123)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:147)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:415)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:641)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:576)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:554)
    at com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpRequest.execute(ApacheHttpRequest.java:67)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:960)
```

Comment: No you can't. The server can't send a TLS alert if it isn't speaking TLS.

Comment: I've updated my comment to show the output from my program.  This is real.  Would appreciate it if you'd remove the down vote.

Comment: It is real, but it isn't caused by talking TLS to a plaintext server. A plaintext server isn't talking TLS, by definition, and you therefore cannot possibly receive a TLS alert from it, by definition. You don't have any information about who downvoted your answer.

Comment: I assumed you down voted - my apologies if that's not the case.  My error message exactly matches the title of this question.  It is a valid path/test case to get this error message and I have a solution which might help others.  Respectfully, I don't think it matters if it's caused by a TLS server  error response or not.  Someone will land here from google and my answer might help if they made same mistake.

Comment: I haven't said anything about your error message. I am commenting on your incorrect claim that it is due to 'mistakenly using HTTPS instead of HTTP'. It isn't, and it can't be, for reasons which I have stated and which you have not addressed in any way. Using HTTP will certainly make it go away, obviously, as there are no TLS alerts in plaintext, but doesn't address the underlying problem.

Comment: Thanks for continuing this conversation.  Once I agree, then I will stop (not trying to "win" - rather, I just want to understand your point better).  How did I make an incorrect claim?  The server was running http and the client tried to use https.  When I switched the client to http, everything worked and it addressed my underlying problem, which was the wrong client-side protocol.  Valid problem (which someone else might repeat), valid solution and error message matches title.  What's not to like?

Comment: You made the incorrect claim that the OP's handshake failure, and this one, were caused by talking to a plaintext server. They weren't. You can't receive a TLS alert from a server that isn't speaking TLS, and you did receive one. I've already stated all this.. You get a different exception when talking to a plaintext server.

Answer (score 2):

Ugg! This turned out to simply be a Java version issue for me.  I got the handshake error using JRE 1.6 and everything worked perfectly using JRE 1.8.0_144.

Answer (score 1):

Mine was a `TLS` version incompatible error.

Previously it was `TLSv1` I changed it `TLSV1.2` this solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue; upgrading to Apache HTTPClient 4.5.3 fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the website just can use TLSv1.2. and i use apache httpclient 4.5.6, i use this code and install jce to solve this (JDK1.7):

jce

jdk7 http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html

jdk 8 http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html

code:

```
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getDefault();

  SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConnectionFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
      sslContext,
      new String[]{"TLSv1.2"}, // important
      null,
      NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE);

  Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> registry = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create()
      .register("https", sslConnectionFactory)
      .register("http", PlainConnectionSocketFactory.INSTANCE)
      .build();

  HttpClientConnectionManager ccm = new BasicHttpClientConnectionManager(registry);
  httpclient = HttpClientBuilder.create().
      .setSSLSocketFactory(sslConnectionFactory)
      .setConnectionManager(ccm)
      .build();
```

Answer (score 1):

To troubleshoot from developer (item 1) and system admin (item 2 and 3) perspective:

1. Enable SSL handshake debug at Java via `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake:verbose`.
2. Install ssldump at server via `sudo apt install ssldump` or compile from source by following this [link](https://pequalsnp-team.github.io/cheatsheet/ssldump) if you observe `Unknown value` in cipher when you run below step.
3. At server, `sudo ssldump -k <your-private-key> -i <your-network-interface>`
4. Check the log about real [reason](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6353956/418439) of the failure.

Example of not working handshake of ssldump log:

```
New TCP connection #1: 10.1.68.86(45308) <-> 10.1.68.83(5671)
1 1  0.0111 (0.0111)  C>S  Handshake
      ClientHello
        Version 3.3
        cipher suites
        TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
        TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
        TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
        TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
        TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
        TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
        TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
        TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
        TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
        TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
        TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
        TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
        TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
        TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
        TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
        TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
        TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
        TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
        TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
        TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
        TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
        TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
        TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
        TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
        TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
        TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
        TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
        TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
        TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
        TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
        TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
        TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
        TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
        TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
        TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
        TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
        TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
        TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
        TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
        TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
        TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
        TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
        TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV
        compression methods
                  NULL
1 2  0.0122 (0.0011)  S>C  Alert
    level           fatal
    value           insufficient_security
1    0.0126 (0.0004)  S>C  TCP RST
```

Example of successful handshake of ssldump log

```
New TCP connection #1: 10.1.68.86(56558) <-> 10.1.68.83(8443)
1 1  0.0009 (0.0009)  C>S  Handshake
      ClientHello
        Version 3.3
        cipher suites
        TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
        TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
        TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
        Unknown value 0xcca9
        Unknown value 0xcca8
        Unknown value 0xccaa
        TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
        TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
        TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
        TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
        TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
        TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
        TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
        TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
        TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
        TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
        TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
        TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
        TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
        TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
        TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
        TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
        TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
        TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
        TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
        TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
        TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
        TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV
        compression methods
                  NULL
1 2  0.0115 (0.0106)  S>C  Handshake
      ServerHello
        Version 3.3
        session_id[0]=

        cipherSuite         TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
        compressionMethod                   NULL
1 3  0.0115 (0.0000)  S>C  Handshake
      Certificate
1 4  0.0115 (0.0000)  S>C  Handshake
      ServerKeyExchange
Not enough data. Found 294 bytes (expecting 32767)
1 5    0.0115   (0.0000)    S>C    Handshake
        ServerHelloDone
1 6    0.0141   (0.0025)    C>S    Handshake
        ClientKeyExchange
Not enough data. Found 31 bytes (expecting 16384)
1 7    0.0141   (0.0000)    C>S    ChangeCipherSpec
1 8    0.0141   (0.0000)    C>S      Handshake
1 9    0.0149   (0.0008)    S>C    Handshake
1 10   0.0149   (0.0000)    S>C    ChangeCipherSpec
1 11   0.0149   (0.0000)    S>C      Handshake
```

Example of not working Java log

```
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|43|SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1|2019-07-03 17:35:01.778 MYT|HandshakeContext.java:294|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|43|SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1|2019-07-03 17:35:01.779 MYT|HandshakeContext.java:294|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|43|SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1|2019-07-03 17:35:01.779 MYT|HandshakeContext.java:294|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|43|SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1|2019-07-03 17:35:01.780 MYT|HandshakeContext.java:294|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|43|SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1|2019-07-03 17:35:01.780 MYT|HandshakeContext.java:294|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|43|SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1|2019-07-03 17:35:01.780 MYT|HandshakeContext.java:294|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|43|SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1|2019-07-03 17:35:01.781 MYT|HandshakeContext.java:294|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|43|SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1|2019-07-03 17:35:01.781 MYT|HandshakeContext.java:294|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|43|SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1|2019-07-03 17:35:01.781 MYT|HandshakeContext.java:294|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|43|SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1|2019-07-03 17:35:01.782 MYT|HandshakeContext.java:294|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|43|SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1|2019-07-03 17:35:01.782 MYT|HandshakeContext.java:294|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|43|SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1|2019-07-03 17:35:01.782 MYT|HandshakeContext.java:294|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|43|SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1|2019-07-03 17:35:01.782 MYT|HandshakeContext.java:294|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|43|SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1|2019-07-03 17:35:01.783 MYT|HandshakeContext.java:294|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|43|SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1|2019-07-03 17:35:01.783 MYT|HandshakeContext.java:294|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|43|SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1|2019-07-03 17:35:01.783 MYT|HandshakeContext.java:294|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|43|SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1|2019-07-03 17:35:01.783 MYT|HandshakeContext.java:294|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|43|SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1|2019-07-03 17:35:01.783 MYT|HandshakeContext.java:294|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|43|SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1|2019-07-03 17:35:01.784 MYT|HandshakeContext.java:294|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|43|SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1|2019-07-03 17:35:01.784 MYT|HandshakeContext.java:294|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: T LS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|43|SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1|2019-07-03 17:35:01.784 MYT|HandshakeContext.java:294|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|43|SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1|2019-07-03 17:35:01.784 MYT|HandshakeContext.java:294|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|43|SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1|2019-07-03 17:35:01.784 MYT|HandshakeContext.java:294|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|43|SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1|2019-07-03 17:35:01.784 MYT|HandshakeContext.java:294|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|43|SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1|2019-07-03 17:35:01.784 MYT|HandshakeContext.java:294|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|43|SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1|2019-07-03 17:35:01.785 MYT|HandshakeContext.java:294|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|43|SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1|2019-07-03 17:35:01.785 MYT|HandshakeContext.java:294|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|43|SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1|2019-07-03 17:35:01.785 MYT|HandshakeContext.java:294|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|43|SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1|2019-07-03 17:35:01.785 MYT|HandshakeContext.java:294|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|43|SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1|2019-07-03 17:35:01.785 MYT|HandshakeContext.java:294|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|43|SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1|2019-07-03 17:35:01.785 MYT|HandshakeContext.java:294|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|43|SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1|2019-07-03 17:35:01.785 MYT|HandshakeContext.java:294|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|43|SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1|2019-07-03 17:35:01.785 MYT|HandshakeContext.java:294|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|43|SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1|2019-07-03 17:35:01.786 MYT|HandshakeContext.java:294|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|43|SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1|2019-07-03 17:35:01.786 MYT|HandshakeContext.java:294|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|43|SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1|2019-07-03 17:35:01.786 MYT|HandshakeContext.java:294|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|43|SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1|2019-07-03 17:35:01.786 MYT|HandshakeContext.java:294|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|43|SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1|2019-07-03 17:35:01.786 MYT|HandshakeContext.java:294|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|43|SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1|2019-07-03 17:35:01.786 MYT|HandshakeContext.java:294|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLS10 javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|43|SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1|2019-07-03 17:35:01.786 MYT|HandshakeContext.java:294|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|43|SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1|2019-07-03 17:35:01.786 MYT|HandshakeContext.java:294|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|43|SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1|2019-07-03 17:35:01.787 MYT|HandshakeContext.java:294|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|43|SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1|2019-07-03 17:35:01.818 MYT|SignatureScheme.java:282|Signature algorithm, ed25519, is not supported by the underlying providers
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|43|SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1|2019-07-03 17:35:01.818 MYT|SignatureScheme.java:282|Signature algorithm, ed448, is not supported by the underlying providers
javax.net.ssl|ALL|43|SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1|2019-07-03 17:35:01.822 MYT|SignatureScheme.java:358|Ignore disabled signature sheme: rsa_md5
javax.net.ssl|INFO|43|SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1|2019-07-03 17:35:01.822 MYT|AlpnExtension.java:161|No available application protocols
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|43|SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1|2019-07-03 17:35:01.823 MYT|SSLExtensions.java:256|Ignore, context unavailable extension: application_layer_protocol_negotiation
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|43|SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1|2019-07-03 17:35:01.823 MYT|SSLExtensions.java:256|Ignore, context unavailable extension: renegotiation_info
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|43|SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1|2019-07-03 17:35:01.825 MYT|ClientHello.java:651|Produced ClientHello handshake message (
"ClientHello": {
  "client version"      : "TLSv1.2",
  "random"              : "FB BC CD 7C 17 65 86 49 3E 1C 15 37 24 94 7D E7 60 44 1B B8 F4 18 21 D0 E1 B1 31 0D E1 80 D6 A7",
  "session id"          : "",
  "cipher suites"       : "[TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC02C), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC02B), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC030), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x009D), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC02E), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC032), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x009F), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x00A3), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC02F), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x009C), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC02D), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC031), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x009E), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x00A2), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384(0xC024), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384(0xC028), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256(0x003D), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384(0xC026), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384(0xC02A), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256(0x006B), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256(0x006A), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0xC00A), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0xC014), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0x0035), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0xC005), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0xC00F), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0x0039), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0x0038), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0xC023), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0xC027), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0x003C), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0xC025), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0xC029), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0x0067), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0x0040), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0xC009), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0xC013), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0x002F), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0xC004), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0xC00E), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0x0033), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0x0032), TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV(0x00FF)]",
  "compression methods" : "00",  "extensions"          : [
    "server_name (0)": {
      type=host_name (0), value=mq.tpc-ohcis.moh.gov.my
    },
    "status_request (5)": {
      "certificate status type": ocsp
      "OCSP status request": {
        "responder_id": <empty>
        "request extensions": {
          <empty>
        }
      }
    },
    "supported_groups (10)": {
      "versions": [secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp256k1, ffdhe2048, ffdhe3072, ffdhe4096, ffdhe6144, ffdhe8192]
    },
    "ec_point_formats (11)": {
      "formats": [uncompressed]
    },
    "signature_algorithms (13)": {
      "signature schemes": [ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256, ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384, ecdsa_secp512r1_sha512, rsa_pss_rsae_sha256, rsa_pss_rsae_sha384, rsa_pss_rsae_sha512, rsa_pss_pss_sha256, rsa_pss_pss_sha384, rsa_pss_pss_sha512, rsa_pkcs1_sha256, rsa_pkcs1_sha384, rsa_pkcs1_sha512, dsa_sha256, ecdsa_sha224, rsa_sha224, dsa_sha224, ecdsa_sha1, rsa_pkcs1_sha1, dsa_sha1]
    },
    "signature_algorithms_cert (50)": {
      "signature schemes": [ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256, ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384, ecdsa_secp512r1_sha512, rsa_pss_rsae_sha256, rsa_pss_rsae_sha384, rsa_pss_rsae_sha512, rsa_pss_pss_sha256, rsa_pss_pss_sha384, rsa_pss_pss_sha512, rsa_pkcs1_sha256, rsa_pkcs1_sha384, rsa_pkcs1_sha512, dsa_sha256, ecdsa_sha224, rsa_sha224, dsa_sha224, ecdsa_sha1, rsa_pkcs1_sha1, dsa_sha1]
    },
    "status_request_v2 (17)": {
      "cert status request": {
        "certificate status type": ocsp_multi
        "OCSP status request": {
          "responder_id": <empty>
          "request extensions": {
            <empty>
          }
        }      }
    },
    "extended_master_secret (23)": {
      <empty>
    },
    "supported_versions (43)": {
      "versions": [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    }
  ]
}
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|43|SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1|2019-07-03 17:35:01.829 MYT|Alert.java:238|Received alert message (
"Alert": {
  "level"      : "fatal",
  "description": "insufficient_security"
}
)
```

Answer (score 1):

On checking i found the issue was java 7, after I changed it to java 8 , it started working. Below one is the problematic version.

```
java -version
java version "1.7.0_101"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_101-b61)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.101-b61, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer : I am not aware if the answer will be helpful for many people,just sharing because it might .*

I was getting this error while using Parasoft SOATest to send request XML(SOAP) .

The issue was that I had **selected the wrong alias** from the dropdown after adding the certificate and authenticating it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had one issue with the version 1.1. I was reproducing the issue easily with curl. The server didn't support lower versions than TLS1.2.

This received handshake issue:

```
curl --insecure --tlsv1.1 -i https://youhost --noproxy "*"
```

With version 1.2 it was working fine:

```
curl --insecure --tlsv1.2 -i https://youhost --noproxy "*"
```

The server was running a Weblogic, and adding this argument in setEnvDomain.sh made it to work with TLSv1.1:

```
-Dweblogic.security.SSL.minimumProtocolVersion=TLSv1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is occurring because of the java version. I was using 1.8.0.231 JDK and getting this error. I have degraded my java version from 1.8.0.231 to 1.8.0.171, Now It is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my case issue occurred due to broken java-11 in my Linux distr (Alt Linux 10).

First, check which TLS use your app. For example, run app with `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake:verbose`

`/usr/bin/java -Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake:verbose -jar /jenkins_slave/slave.jar -jnlpUrl https://jenkins-master.jnlp SECRET -workDir /jenkins_slav`e

I saw:

```
"ClientHello": {
  "client version"      : "TLSv1.2",
```

TLSv1.2.

Check which ciphers support your site:

```
# OpenSSL requires the port number.
SERVER=$1
DELAY=1
ciphers=$(openssl ciphers 'ALL:eNULL' | sed -e 's/:/ /g')
    
echo Obtaining cipher list from $(openssl version).
    
for cipher in ${ciphers[@]}
do
  echo -n Testing $cipher...
  result=$(echo -n | openssl s_client -tls1_2 -cipher "$cipher" -connect $SERVER 2>&1)
  if [[ "$result" =~ ":error:" ]] ; then
    error=$(echo -n $result | cut -d':' -f6)
    echo NO \($error\)
  else
    if [[ "$result" =~ "Cipher is ${cipher}" || "$result" =~ "Cipher    :" ]] ; then
      echo YES
    else
      echo UNKNOWN RESPONSE
      echo $result
    fi
  fi
  sleep $DELAY
done
```

Replace **-tls1_2** in script to your TLS version.

Then run script:

```
bash /path_to_sctipt server_address:443
```

server_address should be without full path and without https.

Example:

```
bash /tmp/1.sh my-site:443
```

Then i receive results:

```
Testing ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384...YES
Testing ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305...YES
Testing ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256...YES
Testing ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384...YES
Testing ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256...YES
Testing ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA...YES
Testing ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA...YES
```

Then install java-devel package (java-11-openjdk-devel in my distr) and run (one-line command):

```
jrunscript -e "java.util.Arrays.asList(javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault().getSupportedCipherSuites()).stream().forEach(println)"
```

I receive:

```
TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV
```

There  are no matches So, my java does not support any chiphers which use my-site.

**Solution:** install java via other ways. Just replace broken java (I installed java on Alt Linux 9 from Alt Linux 8)

Also create bug-report if you can. I have created bug to Alt linux p10 team: https://bugzilla.altlinux.org/show_bug.cgi?id=47484#c1