# SSLSocket exception handshake error when trying to send to SSLServerSocket

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, jsse, sslhandshakeexception

it's my first times to deal with SSLSockets ,

i created SSLServerSocket and SSLSocket ,

the ServerSocket run ok ,
but when trying to run the SSLSocket (Client) , it's don't run , and this error appear to me :

> SEVERE: null
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
>       at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
>       at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
>       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1961)
>       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1077)
>       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
>       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
>       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
>       at chat.SS.(SS.java:45)
>       at chat.SS.main(SS.java:70)

this is the code for SSLServerSocket Class:

```
public class SSocket implements Runnable{    
    SSLServerSocket ss;
    DataOutputStream doo;
    DataInputStream di;

    public SSocket(){
        try {
                System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore",System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/src/cacerts.jks");
                System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword","ja142236");

            SSLServerSocketFactory sf = (SSLServerSocketFactory) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();

            ss = (SSLServerSocket) sf.createServerSocket(2149);
            //ss.setSoTimeout(5000);

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SSocket.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        SSLSocket s;
        try {        

                while(true){
                        System.out.println("Waiting Client Message!");

                        s = (SSLSocket) ss.accept();
                        System.out.println("Acceptted!"+s.getRemoteSocketAddress());
                        s.close();
                 }

         } catch (IOException ex) {
                 System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
         }finally{
            try {
                ss.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(SSocket.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SSocket ss = new SSocket();
        ss.run();
    }

}
```

and for the SSLSocket (Client) which error appear when run it :

```
public class SS {
    public SS() throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, KeyManagementException{
        try {
                /*
                System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/src/cacerts.jks");
                System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "ja142236"); 
            */
                KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
                ks.load(new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/src/cacerts.jks"), ("ahmed149").toCharArray());
                TrustManagerFactory kmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
                kmf.init(ks);
                SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSLv3");
                sslcontext.init(null, kmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

                SSLSocketFactory sf = (SSLSocketFactory) sslcontext.getSocketFactory();
                SSLSocket s = (SSLSocket) sf.createSocket("localhost",2149);
                s.startHandshake();

                DataOutputStream doo = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

            DataInputStream di = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());

            doo.writeUTF(" Hiii From Client");

            System.out.println(di.readUTF());

            doo.close();
            di.close();
                        s.close();


        } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SS.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SS.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, KeyManagementException{
        new SS();
    }
}
```

so what i forgot to do for the class of client ?

thank you,

Edit 1:
i enabled debug , this is the debug :

```
    keyStore is : 
keyStore type is : jks
keyStore provider is : 
init keystore
init keymanager of type SunX509
trustStore is: D:\Java\learn\Chat\src\cacerts.jks
trustStore type is : jks
trustStore provider is : 
init truststore
adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: EMAILADDRESS=admin@server.com, CN=localhost, OU=Inc., O=server, L=CA, ST=KFS, C=US
  Issuer:  EMAILADDRESS=admin@server.com, CN=localhost, OU=Inc., O=server, L=CA, ST=KFS, C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x821112e48bd394ff
  Valid from Fri Jun 14 15:54:57 EET 2013 until Sat Jun 14 15:54:57 EET 2014

trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Allow unsafe renegotiation: true
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for SSLv3
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for SSLv3
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for SSLv3
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for SSLv3
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for SSLv3
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for SSLv3
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for SSLv3
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA256
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1354403376 bytes = { 85, 58, 178, 64, 15, 222, 86, 91, 231, 60, 74, 9, 113, 221, 77, 62, 87, 208, 53, 100, 37, 103, 21, 16, 172, 127, 133, 167 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV, TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_DH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_NULL_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_NULL_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA, TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_NULL_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_MD5, SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DH_anon_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5, SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, TLS_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_MD5, TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_MD5, TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_SHA, TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5, TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_SHA, TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_MD5]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
***
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 215
0000: 01 00 00 D3 03 01 51 BB   8E 30 55 3A B2 40 0F DE  ......Q..0U:.@..
0010: 56 5B E7 3C 4A 09 71 DD   4D 3E 57 D0 35 64 25 67  V[.<J.q.M>W.5d%g
0020: 15 10 AC 7F 85 A7 00 00   6C C0 09 C0 13 00 2F C0  ........l...../.
0030: 04 C0 0E 00 33 00 32 C0   07 C0 11 00 05 C0 02 C0  ....3.2.........
0040: 0C C0 08 C0 12 00 0A C0   03 C0 0D 00 16 00 13 00  ................
0050: 04 00 FF C0 18 00 34 C0   16 00 18 C0 17 00 1B C0  ......4.........
0060: 06 C0 10 00 02 C0 01 C0   0B C0 15 00 01 00 09 00  ................
0070: 15 00 12 00 1A 00 03 00   17 00 08 00 14 00 11 00  ................
0080: 19 00 20 00 24 00 1F 00   23 00 1E 00 22 00 28 00  .. .$...#...".(.
0090: 2B 00 26 00 29 01 00 00   3E 00 0A 00 34 00 32 00  +.&.)...>...4.2.
00A0: 17 00 01 00 03 00 13 00   15 00 06 00 07 00 09 00  ................
00B0: 0A 00 18 00 0B 00 0C 00   19 00 0D 00 0E 00 0F 00  ................
00C0: 10 00 11 00 02 00 12 00   04 00 05 00 14 00 08 00  ................
00D0: 16 00 0B 00 02 01 00                               .......
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 215
[Raw write]: length = 220
0000: 16 03 01 00 D7 01 00 00   D3 03 01 51 BB 8E 30 55  ...........Q..0U
0010: 3A B2 40 0F DE 56 5B E7   3C 4A 09 71 DD 4D 3E 57  :.@..V[.<J.q.M>W
0020: D0 35 64 25 67 15 10 AC   7F 85 A7 00 00 6C C0 09  .5d%g........l..
0030: C0 13 00 2F C0 04 C0 0E   00 33 00 32 C0 07 C0 11  .../.....3.2....
0040: 00 05 C0 02 C0 0C C0 08   C0 12 00 0A C0 03 C0 0D  ................
0050: 00 16 00 13 00 04 00 FF   C0 18 00 34 C0 16 00 18  ...........4....
0060: C0 17 00 1B C0 06 C0 10   00 02 C0 01 C0 0B C0 15  ................
0070: 00 01 00 09 00 15 00 12   00 1A 00 03 00 17 00 08  ................
0080: 00 14 00 11 00 19 00 20   00 24 00 1F 00 23 00 1E  ....... .$...#..
0090: 00 22 00 28 00 2B 00 26   00 29 01 00 00 3E 00 0A  .".(.+.&.)...>..
00A0: 00 34 00 32 00 17 00 01   00 03 00 13 00 15 00 06  .4.2............
00B0: 00 07 00 09 00 0A 00 18   00 0B 00 0C 00 19 00 0D  ................
00C0: 00 0E 00 0F 00 10 00 11   00 02 00 12 00 04 00 05  ................
00D0: 00 14 00 08 00 16 00 0B   00 02 01 00              ............
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 15 03 01 00 02                                     .....
[Raw read]: length = 2
0000: 02 28                                              .(
main, READ: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
main, RECV TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
Jun 14, 2013 11:42:08 PM chat.SS <init>
SEVERE: null
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1961)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1077)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
    at chat.SS.<init>(SS.java:44)
    at chat.SS.main(SS.java:69)
```

Comment: Please post the debug trace at the server.

Comment: @EJP i put it in individual comment because it's long :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Received fatal alert: handshake\_failure through SSLHandshakeException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353849/received-fatal-alert-handshake-failure-through-sslhandshakeexception)

Comment: @Makoto Or possibly not. There isn't enough information in the other question to say.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a certificate for your server.

The `javax.net.ssl.keyStore` property should refer to a key store that contains *your* certificates in entries with the corresponding private keys.