# java https client throws "Received fatal alert: handshake_failure" with JDK 1.5 but works on JDK1.6

Tags: java, https, client, java-5

I am runnning a simple java httpsclient. It gives handshake_failure error when compiled and running with jdk1.5 . But works fine with jdk1.6 . I cannot upgrade my code to jdk 1.6. Is there anyway I can get this working with jdk 1.5

Answer (score 0):

Maybe each JDK is using a different keystore, so one keystore contains a key allowing the connection, and the other does not.

See [Received fatal alert: handshake_failure through SSLHandshakeException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353849/received-fatal-alert-handshake-failure-through-sslhandshakeexception) for details of how to enable SSL connection.

Answer (score 0):

Complementing the 1st answer, try to add the certificate to the keystore on your jdk1.5 with the java keytool

Comment: (This post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer, or just post it as a comment to the other answer).