# Error when trying to create a new JBOSS OpenShift project

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, openshift

I am trying to have a play around with openshift, but am running into a config issue at the first hurdle.

i have RedHatJBOSS Developer Studio 8.0.0 installed, and have the JBOSS Integration and SOA Development Plugin installed.

I also have an openshift user account and can login just fine to their website.

Basically, when I select the create openshift project from the JBoss central page, and enter my valid openshift credentials and pres next, it tries to connect and immediately throws an error stating an SSL handshake exception occurred (details below).

I am a bit lost if I am honest; is there something I need to install?

I am using JRE 7 in case that is significant

```
com.openshift.client.OpenShiftEndpointException: Could not request https://openshift.redhat.com/broker/rest/api: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at com.openshift.internal.client.RestService.request(RestService.java:120)
    at com.openshift.internal.client.RestService.request(RestService.java:92)
    at com.openshift.internal.client.AbstractOpenShiftConnectionFactory.getConnection(AbstractOpenShiftConnectionFactory.java:36)
    at com.openshift.client.OpenShiftConnectionFactory.getConnection(OpenShiftConnectionFactory.java:198)
    at com.openshift.client.OpenShiftConnectionFactory.getConnection(OpenShiftConnectionFactory.java:158)
    at com.openshift.client.OpenShiftConnectionFactory.getConnection(OpenShiftConnectionFactory.java:114)
    at com.openshift.client.OpenShiftConnectionFactory.getConnection(OpenShiftConnectionFactory.java:103)
    at org.jboss.tools.openshift.express.internal.core.connection.Connection.createUser(Connection.java:229)
    at org.jboss.tools.openshift.express.internal.core.connection.Connection.connect(Connection.java:205)
    at org.jboss.tools.openshift.express.internal.ui.wizard.connection.ConnectionWizardPageModel.connect(ConnectionWizardPageModel.java:247)
    at org.jboss.tools.openshift.express.internal.ui.wizard.connection.ConnectionWizardPage$ConnectJob.run(ConnectionWizardPage.java:479)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: com.openshift.internal.client.httpclient.HttpClientException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at com.openshift.internal.client.httpclient.UrlConnectionHttpClient.createException(UrlConnectionHttpClient.java:201)
    at com.openshift.internal.client.httpclient.UrlConnectionHttpClient.request(UrlConnectionHttpClient.java:161)
    at com.openshift.internal.client.httpclient.UrlConnectionHttpClient.request(UrlConnectionHttpClient.java:140)
    at com.openshift.internal.client.httpclient.UrlConnectionHttpClient.get(UrlConnectionHttpClient.java:99)
    at com.openshift.internal.client.RestService.request(RestService.java:160)
    at com.openshift.internal.client.RestService.request(RestService.java:107)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:85)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:541)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1686)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1684)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:330)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1682)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1255)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:479)
    at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.b.getResponseCode(b.java:40)
    at com.openshift.internal.client.httpclient.UrlConnectionHttpClient.createException(UrlConnectionHttpClient.java:184)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at com.ibm.jsse2.j.a(j.java:33)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.j.a(j.java:31)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.b(qc.java:190)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.a(qc.java:456)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.h(qc.java:352)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.a(qc.java:523)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.startHandshake(qc.java:730)
    at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.c.afterConnect(c.java:70)
    at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.d.connect(d.java:9)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1311)
    at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.b.getInputStream(b.java:89)
    at com.openshift.internal.client.httpclient.UrlConnectionHttpClient.request(UrlConnectionHttpClient.java:157)
    ... 15 more
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353849/received-fatal-alert-handshake-failure-through-sslhandshakeexception

Answer (score 1):

This looks very weird, I didnt spot this so far. SSL handshake is failing for some unknown reason.

What is the exact version of your JDK7?
What is your OS?

Cheers
Andre

Comment: It appeared to be related to missing Maven repositories - I resolved it by adding the repositories to the Maven profile on the project.

Comment: hmm, to be honest I doubt that adding maven repositories would solve it. IMHO some implicit or additional manipulation must have solved the problem for you since the OpenShift Eclipse tooling  does not rely on maven repositories at runtime.