# SSLHandshakeException when connecting to Openshift from EclipseIDE... How to solve?

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, openshift, jboss-tools

I'm trying to connect to Openshift from Eclipse Mars IDE.

I can very well login to my Openshift account on the web.... Also, going by the error message, I even created new private/public keys and retried connecting but still to no avail. Then I ran a JBossTools update, and tried again, yet no solution.

Here's the closest JBoss Tools BugTrack that I found related to my case, https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBIDE-14760, but it turns out this is recorded as fixed since JBossTools 4.1.0, whereas I have 4.3.0 on both Mars and Luna

What's even more disturbing is the fact that I've previously been able to make this connection some time ago with Eclipse Luna, then I went back to Luna and tried again but still was unable to make the Openshift connection.

See screenshots of the error messages below;

***Eclipse Mars (Error Screenshot below);***

[image]

***Eclipse Luna (Error Screenshot below);***

[image]

And following is the StackTrace from the logs looks as follows:

```
!ENTRY org.jboss.tools.openshift.express.ui 4 4 2015-10-09 18:05:58.143
!MESSAGE Could not request https://openshift.redhat.com/broker/rest/api: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No X509TrustManager implementation available
!STACK 0
com.openshift.client.OpenShiftEndpointException: Could not request https://openshift.redhat.com/broker/rest/api: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No X509TrustManager implementation available
    at com.openshift.internal.client.RestService.request(RestService.java:120)
    at com.openshift.internal.client.RestService.request(RestService.java:92)
    at com.openshift.internal.client.AbstractOpenShiftConnectionFactory.getConnection(AbstractOpenShiftConnectionFactory.java:36)
    at com.openshift.client.OpenShiftConnectionFactory.getConnection(OpenShiftConnectionFactory.java:198)
    at com.openshift.client.OpenShiftConnectionFactory.getConnection(OpenShiftConnectionFactory.java:158)
    at com.openshift.client.OpenShiftConnectionFactory.getConnection(OpenShiftConnectionFactory.java:114)
    at com.openshift.client.OpenShiftConnectionFactory.getConnection(OpenShiftConnectionFactory.java:103)
    at org.jboss.tools.openshift.express.internal.core.connection.Connection.createUser(Connection.java:229)
    at org.jboss.tools.openshift.express.internal.core.connection.Connection.connect(Connection.java:205)
    at org.jboss.tools.openshift.express.internal.ui.wizard.connection.ConnectionWizardPageModel.connect(ConnectionWizardPageModel.java:247)
    at org.jboss.tools.openshift.express.internal.ui.wizard.connection.ConnectionWizardPage$ConnectJob.run(ConnectionWizardPage.java:479)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: com.openshift.internal.client.httpclient.HttpClientException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No X509TrustManager implementation available
    at com.openshift.internal.client.httpclient.UrlConnectionHttpClient.createException(UrlConnectionHttpClient.java:201)
    at com.openshift.internal.client.httpclient.UrlConnectionHttpClient.request(UrlConnectionHttpClient.java:161)
    at com.openshift.internal.client.httpclient.UrlConnectionHttpClient.request(UrlConnectionHttpClient.java:140)
    at com.openshift.internal.client.httpclient.UrlConnectionHttpClient.get(UrlConnectionHttpClient.java:99)
    at com.openshift.internal.client.RestService.request(RestService.java:160)
    at com.openshift.internal.client.RestService.request(RestService.java:107)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No X509TrustManager implementation available
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at com.openshift.internal.client.httpclient.UrlConnectionHttpClient.createException(UrlConnectionHttpClient.java:184)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No X509TrustManager implementation available
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.openshift.internal.client.httpclient.UrlConnectionHttpClient.request(UrlConnectionHttpClient.java:157)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No X509TrustManager implementation available
    at sun.security.ssl.DummyX509TrustManager.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
    ... 29 more
```

Similar SO posts such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27923831/error-when-trying-to-create-a-new-jboss-openshift-project) have offered little or no concrete help either.

Thanks.

Comment: I tried using jdk8 and vanilla Eclipse Luna but couldn't reproduce your error. Can you please specify what's your environment (OS, jdk)? Furthermore I'd highly encourage you to verify that the keystore of your jdk is properly set up. Googling one can see many with similar symptoms that then found out their java keystore went corrupt/misconfigured.

Comment: OS & JDK are... windows8 / jdk7

Comment: Actually solved this already. I only updated my windows installer for Eclipse Mars, before re-installing and then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

please make sure you use latest JDK version since older ones had issues with ssh after heartbleed.

if you see something else please report issue in https://jira.jboss.org/jira/browse/JBIDE

Answer (score 0):

Ok here's what I did and afterwards I was able to establish the Openshift connection from Eclipse Mars

I suspect it was an outdated windows installer problem because all I did was just attempt to re-install my Eclipse Mars which i got from [here](https://eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/mars/1/eclipse-jee-mars-1-win32-x86_64.zip)

**NOTE -** in my previous installation, I did not notice the update option in the installer so I installed without updating. Well, I believe that copy did not contain the Bug Fixes that solved this particular problem

However, when I attempted to re-install, i noticed the update icon at the top right corner *(see image below)* so I first of all updated before continuing with the installation process. I guess this just downloaded and applied all the bug fixes before installing.

[image]

Afterwards, I tried to establish the OpenShift connection from within my Eclipse Mars IDE without changing anything (*...when I say '**anything**', I mean my public/private key pair*), and Voila, the connection got established.

I hope this helps anyone who runs into this problem and bumps into this post.

Comment: still a bit misterious but thanks a lot for sharing!