# Burp Suite Error "Received fatal alert: handshake_failure"

Tags: java, burp

While using Burp Proxy for a given site I am getting the above error and no response is getting displayed.

```
Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Received fatal alert: handshake\_failure through SSLHandshakeException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353849/received-fatal-alert-handshake-failure-through-sslhandshakeexception)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67360622/burp-suite-ssl-error-handshake-failure-alert-or-err-ssl-protocol-error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67360622/burp-suite-ssl-error-handshake-failure-alert-or-err-ssl-protocol-error

Answer (score 0):

Check to see your Burp Alerts log if there is a “You have limited key lengths available" message there. If so, you will need to replace the "strong" versions of Java Cryptography Extension with the "unlimited" strength ones.

1. Find out your jre version: `[path_to_jre]/java -version`
2. Search for "JCE [your_jre_version]"
3. Extract the files to [path_to_jre]/lib/security according to the README.
4. Restart Burp.