# Burp Suite SSL ERROR HANDSHAKE FAILURE ALERT OR ERR SSL PROTOCOL ERROR

Tags: java, burp

My Burp Suite was working properly but failed after a while and the message in FireFox"SSL_ERROR_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE_ALERT" and in Chrome "ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR" was displayed in the browser. The valid Burp Suite certificate was also fully integrated into the browser.
I did the following but it didn't work

1. Get a new certificate output from Burp Suite and import it
2. Use a new browser with a new certificate
3. Reinstall Burp Suite and insert a new certificate
4. Delete and change the used jdk version
5. Remove all Burp Suite registry keys
6. Remove all jdk registry keys
7. Use different versions of jdk

But none of them were solutions, and only changing the Windows user and creating a new user would solve the problem, which in my opinion was not true at all.
After many tests and different R&Ds, I finally found the solution to the problem
The problem is the incompatibility of the official JDK and JDK required by the Burp Suite, and to solve the problem, the following steps must be followed.

1. Download the Professional Burp Suite version from ***https://portswigger.net***
2. Install it in ***C:\Burp_Suite***
3. Jar Copy your previous Burp file and Loader to
   ***C:\Burp_Suite\jre\bin*** and run it using the following command:
   ***"C:\Burp_Suite\jre\bin\java.exe -javaagent:BurpSuiteLoader_v.XXX.jar -noverify -jar burpsuite_pro_vXXX.jar"***
4. Enjoy your Burp Suite

Comment: Can't you use the [embedded browser](https://portswigger.net/burp/documentation/desktop/functions/embedded-browser)?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similer problem. I solved it after 2 steps.

1. Chrome Settings > Privacy and security > Security > Always use secure connections (Make it OFF. I disabled this option for some CTF challenges. Use this option wisely because it can be dangerous.)
2. Visit http://burpsuite. Then, click "Download CA Certificate" on the website. After the download, go to: Chrome Settings > Privacy and security > Security > Manage device certificates. On the pop-up page, import the downloaded certificate.

I hope my solutions help to the others!

Answer (score 0):

Following the previous solution for versions 2023 and 2024, you can create a bat file in the Windows environment and put the following line of code in it to run the boot and create a shortcut from the bat file on the desktop.
In the Linux environment, put the same line at the end of the jvm options file in the installation location of the application and run Burp Pro directly.
Just note that the code paths for Linux and Windows should match the installation path of the BurpSuite application. My installation path is C:\BurpSuitePro
Note: If you are installing Burp Suite for the first time, you must activate it through Loader.

code:

```
@echo off
"C:\BurpSuitePro\jre\bin\java.exe" "--add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing=ALL-UNNAMED" "--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED" "--add-opens=java.base/jdk.internal.org.objectweb.asm=ALL-UNNAMED" "--add-opens=java.base/jdk.internal.org.objectweb.asm.tree=ALL-UNNAMED" "--add-opens=java.base/jdk.internal.org.objectweb.asm.Opcodes=ALL-UNNAMED" "-javaagent:Dr-FarFar.jar" "-noverify" "-jar" "C:\BurpSuitePro\burpsuite_pro.jar"
```

You can download the files needed to create a key from the link below

```
[Dr_FarFar.jar][1]
[reset_license.bat][2]
[burp.bat][3]
https://s30.picofile.com/file/8471041118/Dr_FarFar.jar.html
https://s30.picofile.com/file/8471041142/reset_license.bat.html
https://s31.picofile.com/file/8471041150/burp.bat.html
```