# Java.lang.NullPointerException error while exporting SSL Certificate BurpSuit

Tags: java, ssl, nullpointerexception, ssl-certificate, burp

I have burp suite installed on windows 10, I tried to configure the certificate and when I try to download it from the embedded browser I see that it is in cer format and can't be added to firefox or chrome, so I tried to export it using burp option in Der format, but it failed with java.lang.NullPointerException error.

[Error Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZJCo.png)

Comment: Chrome/Windows do support PEM encoded certificates, you just have to rename the file to `<something>.cer` and you can open/import it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67360622/burp-suite-ssl-error-handshake-failure-alert-or-err-ssl-protocol-error

Comment: any solutions ?