# Java JDK 7 SSL Issue

Tags: java, ssl, jce

I'm facing a very strange issue and i'm blocked from several days on it
I have a WS client acting on SSL; with JDK 1.5 all orks good; upgrading to JDK 1.7 I'm having the error "javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure"
So i debugged and I arrived to write a very simple and stupid Java main; in JDK 1.5 it works; in JDK 1.7 it doesn't.
By searching and reading Oracle documentation, in my JDK 1.7 environment i did the following steps:

- installed the JDK 1.7 JCE extension downloaded from this URL: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html
- imported the certificate by using the keytool command: keytool -importcert -file C:\certificato\mycert.spcoop.gov_25_05_15.der -alias prenotazioni  -keystore cacerts
- added these JVM parameters: -Djavax.net.debug=all -Dhttps.protocols="TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1,SSLv3"

This is my Java code:

```
SSLSocketFactory sslsocketfactory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
URL url = new URL(https_url);
HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
conn.setSSLSocketFactory(sslsocketfactory);
InputStream inputstream = conn.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader inputstreamreader = new InputStreamReader(inputstream);
BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(inputstreamreader);
String string = null;
while ((string = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null) {
System.out.println("Received " + string);
}
```

When I execute my code, in JDK 5 all works OK; in JDK 7 I have this error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1979)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1086)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1332)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1359)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1301)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
at test.TestWs.main(TestWs.java:261)
```

My javax.net debug in JDK 7 is the following:

```
keyStore is :
keyStore type is : jks
keyStore provider is :
init keystore
init keymanager of type SunX509
trustStore is: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre\lib\security\cacerts
trustStore type is : jks
trustStore provider is :
init truststore
adding as trusted cert:
Subject: CN=SwissSign Platinum CA - G2, O=SwissSign AG, C=CH
Issuer: CN=SwissSign Platinum CA - G2, O=SwissSign AG, C=CH
Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x4eb200670c035d4f
Valid from Wed Oct 25 10:36:00 CEST 2006 until Sat Oct 25 10:36:00
adding as trusted cert:
Subject: CN=Starfield Root Certificate Authority - G2, O="Starfield Technologies, Inc.", L=Scottsdale, ST=Arizona, C=US
Issuer: CN=Starfield Root Certificate Authority - G2, O="Starfield Technologies, Inc.", L=Scottsdale, ST=Arizona, C=US
Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x0
Valid from Tue Sep 01 02:00:00 CEST 2009 until Fri Jan 01 00:59:59 CET 2038
trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
main, setSoTimeout(0) called
Ignoring disabled protocol: SSLv3
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie: GMT: 1432571160 bytes = { 183, 74, 138, 30, 148, 63, 201, 75, 45, 62, 236, 97, 105, 77, 43, 2, 165, 41, 236, 66, 136, 199, 69, 218, 51, 222, 160, 173 }
Session ID: {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods: { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA, MD5withRSA
Extension server_name, server_name: [host_name: regionepuglia.spcoop.gov.it]
***

*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
[
Version: V3
Subject: CN=regionepuglia.spcoop.gov.it, OU=regionepuglia, O=SPCoop, L=Unknown, ST=Unknown, C=IT
Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5
Key: Sun RSA public key, 1024 bits
modulus: 132618727249398576547024477808858924367105537553637063046075664049606165829826937799440779441085443715757852311051661228801872537170391304848984401153128450313724384093034858857147382765618549007154165424372327503199963670471207807167735896793431454627395348393490603992708106531483375397586992903157954592719
public exponent: 65537
Validity: [From: Tue Oct 09 15:49:47 CEST 2012,
To: Fri Oct 09 16:49:47 CEST 2015]
Issuer: CN=SPCoop CA1, OU=Servizi di Sicurezza e Certificazione, O=DigitPA, C=IT
SerialNumber: [ f4]
Certificate Extensions: 5
[1]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 0B E1 2F 63 C8 02 65 44 1E 00 BD E9 91 8A 43 CE ../c..eD......C.
0010: B3 6F 5E 19 .o^.
]
[CN=SPCoop CA1, OU=Servizi di Sicurezza e Certificazione, O=DigitPA, C=IT]
SerialNumber: [ 01]
]
[2]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.31 Criticality=false
CRLDistributionPoints [
[DistributionPoint:
[URIName: ldap://ldapca2.pcoop.gov.it/cn%3DSPCoop%20CA1,ou%3DServizi%20di%20sicurezza%20e%20certificazione,o%3DDigitPA,C%3DIT?certificateRevocationList]
]]
[3]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.32 Criticality=false
CertificatePolicies [
[CertificatePolicyId: [1.3.76.16.3.4.1.1]
[PolicyQualifierInfo: [
qualifierID: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.2.1
qualifier: 0000: 16 2A 68 74 74 70 3A 2F 2F 63 61 2E 53 50 43 6F .*http://ca.SPCo
0010: 6F 70 2E 67 6F 76 2E 69 74 2F 43 50 53 2F 53 50 op.gov.it/CPS/SP
0020: 43 6F 6F 70 5F 43 50 53 2E 68 74 6D Coop_CPS.htm
]] ]
]
[4]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
DigitalSignature
Key_Encipherment
Data_Encipherment
]
[5]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: BD 71 AE 3E 75 F2 CC 46 F2 11 5B 48 6C 29 F3 8E .q.>u..F..[Hl)..
0010: 82 09 98 8E ....
]
]
]
Algorithm: [SHA1withRSA]

SerialNumber: [ 01]
Certificate Extensions: 6
[1]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 0B E1 2F 63 C8 02 65 44 1E 00 BD E9 91 8A 43 CE ../c..eD......C.
0010: B3 6F 5E 19 .o^.
]
[CN=SPCoop CA1, OU=Servizi di Sicurezza e Certificazione, O=DigitPA, C=IT]
SerialNumber: [ 01]
]
[2]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=true
BasicConstraints:[
CA:true
PathLen:2147483647
]
[3]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.31 Criticality=false
CRLDistributionPoints [
[DistributionPoint:
[URIName: ldap://ldapca.spcoop.gov.it/cn%3DSPCoop%20CA1,ou%3DServizi%20di%20sicurezza%20e%20certificazione,o%3DDigitPA,C%3DIT?authorityRevocationList]
]]
[4]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.32 Criticality=false
CertificatePolicies [
[CertificatePolicyId: [1.3.76.16.3.4.1]
[PolicyQualifierInfo: [
qualifierID: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.2.1
qualifier: 0000: 16 2A 68 74 74 70 3A 2F 2F 63 61 2E 53 50 43 6F .*http://ca.SPCo
0010: 6F 70 2E 67 6F 76 2E 69 74 2F 43 50 53 2F 53 50 op.gov.it/CPS/SP
0020: 43 6F 6F 70 5F 43 50 53 2E 68 74 6D Coop_CPS.htm
]] ]
]
[5]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
Key_CertSign
Crl_Sign
]
[6]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 0B E1 2F 63 C8 02 65 44 1E 00 BD E9 91 8A 43 CE ../c..eD......C.
0010: B3 6F 5E 19 .o^.
]
]
]
Algorithm: [SHA1withRSA]
Signature:

***
Found trusted certificate:
[
[
Version: V3
Subject: CN=regionepuglia.spcoop.gov.it, OU=regionepuglia, O=SPCoop, L=Unknown, ST=Unknown, C=IT
Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5
Key: Sun RSA public key, 1024 bits
modulus 132618727249398576547024477808858924367105537553637063046075664049606165829826937799440779441085443715757852311051661228801872537170391304848984401153128450313724384093034858857147382765618549007154165424372327503199963670471207807167735896793431454627395348393490603992708106531483375397586992903157954592719
public exponent: 65537
Validity: [From: Tue Oct 09 15:49:47 CEST 2012,
To: Fri Oct 09 16:49:47 CEST 2015]
Issuer: CN=SPCoop CA1, OU=Servizi di Sicurezza e Certificazione, O=DigitPA, C=IT
SerialNumber: [ f4]
Certificate Extensions: 5
[1]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 0B E1 2F 63 C8 02 65 44 1E 00 BD E9 91 8A 43 CE ../c..eD......C.
0010: B3 6F 5E 19 .o^.
]
[CN=SPCoop CA1, OU=Servizi di Sicurezza e Certificazione, O=DigitPA, C=IT]
SerialNumber: [ 01]
]
[2]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.31 Criticality=false
CRLDistributionPoints [
[DistributionPoint:
[URIName: ldap://ldapca2.spcoop.gov.it/cn%3DSPCoop%20CA1,ou%3DServizi%20di%20sicurezza%20e%20certificazione,o%3DDigitPA,C%3DIT?certificateRevocationList]
]]
[3]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.32 Criticality=false
CertificatePolicies [
[CertificatePolicyId: [1.3.76.16.3.4.1.1]
[PolicyQualifierInfo: [
qualifierID: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.2.1
qualifier: 0000: 16 2A 68 74 74 70 3A 2F 2F 63 61 2E 53 50 43 6F .*http://ca.SPCo
0010: 6F 70 2E 67 6F 76 2E 69 74 2F 43 50 53 2F 53 50 op.gov.it/CPS/SP
0020: 43 6F 6F 70 5F 43 50 53 2E 68 74 6D Coop_CPS.htm
]] ]
]
[4]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
DigitalSignature
Key_Encipherment
Data_Encipherment
]
[5]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: BD 71 AE 3E 75 F2 CC 46 F2 11 5B 48 6C 29 F3 8E .q.>u..F..[Hl)..
0010: 82 09 98 8E ....
]
]
]
Algorithm: [SHA1withRSA]
Signature:

*** ServerHelloDone
[read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes: len = 4
0000: 0E 00 00 00 ....
*** ClientKeyExchange, RSA PreMasterSecret, TLSv1
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes: len = 134
0000: 10 00 00 82 00 80 B0 92 DE FA 46 DC 18 8A FA 3F ..........F....?
0010: AA D1 BE E0 6A 9F E3 0D 45 6A FB FB E1 B0 CC 3E ....j...Ej.....>
0020: 74 89 A0 AD 0C 49 C1 79 E5 23 1F B0 AA 41 73 F6 t....I.y.#...As.
0030: 45 CA ED E4 A3 0E F4 76 46 CE 41 FB 18 FF D2 33 E......vF.A....3
0040: F4 F5 F7 05 80 7F B2 71 BB B8 EF 5D 62 46 C5 49 .......q...]bF.I
0050: 1F 5D 97 FD 23 2D 4B 80 C6 9A 75 DE 7C 76 6F CE .]..#-K...u..vo.
0060: F1 95 27 79 E5 E4 59 60 F4 7D FF 32 4F C9 58 88 ..'y..Y`...2O.X.
0070: 2D AB 76 FD 9E C2 27 51 2B 40 38 2F 75 2A 70 A8 -.v...'Q+@8/u*p.
0080: 9F FE 85 74 9C 19 ...t..
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 134
[Raw write]: length = 139
0000: 16 03 01 00 86 10 00 00 82 00 80 B0 92 DE FA 46 ...............F
0010: DC 18 8A FA 3F AA D1 BE E0 6A 9F E3 0D 45 6A FB ....?....j...Ej.
0020: FB E1 B0 CC 3E 74 89 A0 AD 0C 49 C1 79 E5 23 1F ....>t....I.y.#.
0030: B0 AA 41 73 F6 45 CA ED E4 A3 0E F4 76 46 CE 41 ..As.E......vF.A
0040: FB 18 FF D2 33 F4 F5 F7 05 80 7F B2 71 BB B8 EF ....3.......q...
0050: 5D 62 46 C5 49 1F 5D 97 FD 23 2D 4B 80 C6 9A 75 ]bF.I.]..#-K...u
0060: DE 7C 76 6F CE F1 95 27 79 E5 E4 59 60 F4 7D FF ..vo...'y..Y`...
0070: 32 4F C9 58 88 2D AB 76 FD 9E C2 27 51 2B 40 38 2O.X.-.v...'Q+@8
0080: 2F 75 2A 70 A8 9F FE 85 74 9C 19 /u*p....t..
SESSION KEYGEN:
PreMaster Secret:
0000: 03 03 5E 36 BB 09 5E 03 97 7F 61 4A 47 A3 A9 10 ..^6..^...aJG...
0010: 01 B4 66 BE 3B C0 2E CF B7 F4 20 A6 A9 64 EE 39 ..f.;..... ..d.9
0020: F5 CA D6 55 91 E5 A8 7B 55 E5 E4 79 51 34 9E 74 ...U....U..yQ4.t
CONNECTION KEYGEN:
Client Nonce:
0000: 55 63 4D 18 B7 4A 8A 1E 94 3F C9 4B 2D 3E EC 61 UcM..J...?.K->.a
0010: 69 4D 2B 02 A5 29 EC 42 88 C7 45 DA 33 DE A0 AD iM+..).B..E.3...
Server Nonce:
0000: 55 63 4D 16 FD 2D 24 0C 63 46 70 A4 E7 83 CC 37 UcM..-$.cFp....7
0010: 79 11 24 F8 58 C8 E1 6D 0D 9D 58 77 FA FE 05 8D y.$.X..m..Xw....
Master Secret:
0000: 7E B7 46 B7 05 03 33 54 F0 90 85 F5 72 36 AF 0E ..F...3T....r6..
0010: 56 76 82 8E CE 79 CA 6D 63 94 00 49 89 34 54 6C Vv...y.mc..I.4Tl
0020: E0 06 CD AE 5D 89 3B 77 5B C0 36 4A F5 09 A9 05 ....].;w[.6J....
Client MAC write Secret:
0000: 3F 61 6A 32 17 24 69 5C D0 65 46 71 17 6F 49 D0 ?aj2.$i\.eFq.oI.
0010: 69 6A E9 93 ij..
Server MAC write Secret:
0000: BF 56 23 2C F4 8D B2 38 3F D7 D9 66 D3 B4 7E 58 .V#,...8?..f...X
0010: 93 42 43 86 .BC.
Client write key:
0000: E6 EF BB 72 42 C4 FA 9D 07 55 D0 B0 E5 C6 5B 15 ...rB....U....[.
0010: 89 C1 0D 5F 51 42 C0 5A 2B 16 A1 49 69 00 13 14 ..._QB.Z+..Ii...
Server write key:
0000: 7C 6B 06 B8 1F 7D 1D 8E F9 C8 DC CE B1 69 C3 80 .k...........i..
0010: 66 F1 2E FE 34 CD 55 C2 DE 15 0A 24 7F 5D BD 3F f...4.U....$.].?
Client write IV:
0000: CF FC 8E D5 D0 7E 70 21 38 2C 6D 03 2D 03 80 A8 ......p!8,m.-...
Server write IV:
0000: 4A 2A 03 05 96 AC 85 93 9A D9 26 CD 32 8A 74 BF J*........&.2.t.
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
[Raw write]: length = 6
0000: 14 03 01 00 01 01 ......
*** Finished
verify_data: { 237, 199, 24, 108, 153, 108, 61, 88, 201, 55, 157, 18 }
***
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes: len = 16
0000: 14 00 00 0C ED C7 18 6C 99 6C 3D 58 C9 37 9D 12 .......l.l=X.7..
Padded plaintext before ENCRYPTION: len = 48
0000: 14 00 00 0C ED C7 18 6C 99 6C 3D 58 C9 37 9D 12 .......l.l=X.7..
0010: D0 E6 5D 93 43 CE CE E7 58 F1 9A 99 EA 81 8C 17 ..].C...X.......
0020: 4C 37 EC 44 0B 0B 0B 0B 0B 0B 0B 0B 0B 0B 0B 0B L7.D............
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 48
[Raw write]: length = 53
0000: 16 03 01 00 30 6A 2C 11 84 25 E5 6B AA A5 E0 96 ....0j,..%.k....
0010: C9 FA CB C7 16 AF 57 FD 31 BC A3 3E 4A 09 1A 53 ......W.1..>J..S
0020: 19 69 92 AB 63 3D 75 38 EA 44 33 FC F7 A6 65 51 .i..c=u8.D3...eQ
0030: 84 E8 77 6E 44 ..wnD
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 15 03 01 00 02 .....
[Raw read]: length = 2
0000: 02 28 .(
main, READ: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
main, RECV TLSv1 ALERT: fatal, handshake_failure
%% Invalidated: [Session-1, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA]
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1979)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1086)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1332
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1359)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1301)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
at test.TestWs.main(TestWs.java:261)
```

Since javax.net full debug message is too long, I can't post it here; if you need you can find it here: http://we.tl/Qovj2ZgkaW

Note: this link will be active only for 10 days

Comment: Did you see this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353849/received-fatal-alert-handshake-failure-through-sslhandshakeexception

Comment: The problem happens on the server side so please look there for more detailed information about problems (logs, stderr...). Since the problem is very late in the handshake and no DH or ECDH ciphers are used it is probably not related to ciphers or protocol versions or problems with the certificate.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: @SteffenUllrich IMHO i don't think the problem is on the server side; if it's on the server side, the problem should be raisen alson with JDK 1.5 and JDK 1.4 (I tried the JDK 1.4 and all worked perfectly); it raises only with JDK >= 1.7 (I didn't check with JDK 1.6)

Comment: @JohnSaunders OK; i'll give a look to the link; i didn't see these rules

Comment: @AngeloImmediata: since the server is throwing the error to the client you need to look at the server side **why** the server throws this error. It might be related to what the client does (and does not in earlier JDK) but the error still occurs on the server side so you can only get more detailed information there.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I'll try to schedule a test with who developed the server side of the Web Services... but I can't explain why with old JVM all works good while with newer JVM it doesn't; I'll try to debug the server side

Comment: @AngeloImmediata: you might try to find the differences between these JVM by doing a packet capture and look at the handshakes with wireshark. But to get the real reason why the handshake fails you have to look at the server side. It might be simply an assumption about the traffic on the server side which were only valid for older TLS or JVM versions.  Such things happen a lot and are almost always caused by bugs in the server side implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Try commenting out jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms in JDK/jre/lib/security/java.security, in your JDK7 installation.