# Getting SSLHandshakeException in java

Tags: java, eclipse, ssl, https, digital-certificate

I ma getting SSL Hand Shake error in eclipse while calling https restful web service from simple java stub but, can access this URL from browser after importing Client Digital Certificate to browser which was shared by service provider. Hiding End point URL for security purpose.
Please help me, i am new to consuming https web services from Java Clients.

JAVA stub as below:

```
 try {
          URL url = new URL("https://*********************");
             conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setRequestProperty("enctype","multipart/form-data");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/xml");
            System.out.println("Printing Connetion Object "+conn);
        if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                    + conn.getResponseCode());
        }

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            (conn.getInputStream()))); 
        String output;
        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(output);
        }
        conn.disconnect();
      } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
          System.out.println("MalformedURLException-->"+conn);
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
          System.out.println("IOException-->"+conn);
        e.printStackTrace();

      }
```

Getting Error as below:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:174)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:136)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1720)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:954)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1138)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1165)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1149)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:434)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:166)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1172)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:379)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:318)
```

Comment: import certificate with keytool to your JRE `cacerts`  file.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353849/received-fatal-alert-handshake-failure-through-sslhandshakeexception)

Comment: yes, my friend @FranMontero is right, do exactly that he tells you

Comment: Thanks all for quick replies.. will try as suggested by @FranMontero and will let u all know

Comment: Imported to JRE.. but still same error :(

Comment: Try with that code https://gist.github.com/philipsorst/4380376

Comment: @FranMontero not able to run this code.. As per my understanding in code Host = https End point url, and port = Proxy  SSL port number. Please correct me if i am wrong... i completely new to this SSL stuff.. I really appreciate ur efforts to help me out

Comment: pass `xx.xx.xx.xx:443` to it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If importing to keystore not resolving your issue.. as i was not able to resolve it. 
Then add following line of code. It worked for me.

```
System.setProperty( "javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "D:\\G2B.p12" );  // The path to the .p12 file
          System.setProperty( "javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "****" );  // The password of the p12 file
          System.setProperty( "javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "pkcs12" );  // Default is JKS, we're using PKCS12
```

Comment: Above property settings working for me.. please let me know if any security issues i may get with this approach?