# SoapUI connecting to AWS API Gateway

Tags: ssl, soapui, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm building little SOAP API on AWS Lambda(node.js) behind API Gateway. I have added custom domain with trusted certificate (COMODO RSA Certification Authority) but when I try any request from SoapUI (v5.2.1 on OSX) it fails with `handshake_failure`.

API URL: https://arrivacz-custom.bileto.com/terminal

I have tried to create keystore with public part of certificate and add it to
Project Settings -> WS-Security Configurations -> Keystores and Truststores but it didn't help.

I have also tried to add to add few lines to SoapUI/Contents/vmoptions.txt

```txt
-Dcom.sun.net.ssl.checkRevocation=false
-Dsun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation=true
-Dcom.sun.net.ssl.enableECC=false
-Djavax.net.debug=all
-Dsoapui.https.protocols=TLSv1.2
```

Because I need this just for testing I can go with ignoring all SSL errors but I can't find how to do that.

Can you please suggest me way how to make this working.

SoapUI error log:

```txt
Fri Feb 19 11:49:48 CET 2016:ERROR:javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1959)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1077)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:702)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:122)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.flushBuffer(AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.java:131)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.flush(AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.java:138)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.LoggingSessionOutputBuffer.flush(LoggingSessionOutputBuffer.java:95)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthOutputStream.flush(ContentLengthOutputStream.java:102)
    at org.apache.http.entity.ByteArrayEntity.writeTo(ByteArrayEntity.java:69)
    at org.apache.http.entity.HttpEntityWrapper.writeTo(HttpEntityWrapper.java:96)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.EntityEnclosingRequestWrapper$EntityWrapper.writeTo(EntityEnclosingRequestWrapper.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.impl.entity.EntitySerializer.serialize(EntitySerializer.java:120)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.sendRequestEntity(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:263)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.sendRequestEntity(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:227)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:255)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpClientSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:123)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:633)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:454)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.HttpClientSupport$Helper.execute(HttpClientSupport.java:233)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.HttpClientSupport.execute(HttpClientSupport.java:323)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.HttpClientRequestTransport.submitRequest(HttpClientRequestTransport.java:290)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.HttpClientRequestTransport.sendRequest(HttpClientRequestTransport.java:220)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlSubmit.run(WsdlSubmit.java:119)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

SoapUI log with network debug:

```txt
Fri Feb 19 11:49:01 CET 2016:INFO:initialized soapui-settings from [/Users/jakubriedl/soapui-settings.xml]
Fri Feb 19 11:49:01 CET 2016:INFO:Initializing KeyStore
Fri Feb 19 11:49:02 CET 2016:ERROR:An error occurred [No private keys found in keystore!], see error log for details
Fri Feb 19 11:49:04 CET 2016:INFO:Adding plugin from [/Users/jakubriedl/.soapuios/plugins/soapui-swagger-plugin-2.2-dist.jar]
Fri Feb 19 11:49:04 CET 2016:INFO:Adding plugin from [/Users/jakubriedl/.soapuios/plugins/ready-uxm-plugin-1.0.1-dist.jar]
Fri Feb 19 11:49:05 CET 2016:ERROR:An error occurred [com.eviware.soapui.plugins.auto.factories.AutoDiscoveryMethodFactory], see error log for details
Fri Feb 19 11:49:05 CET 2016:ERROR:An error occurred [com.eviware.soapui.plugins.auto.factories.AutoImportMethodFactory], see error log for details
Fri Feb 19 11:49:05 CET 2016:INFO:Adding plugin from [/Users/jakubriedl/.soapuios/plugins/ready-mqtt-plugin-dist.jar]
Fri Feb 19 11:49:05 CET 2016:ERROR:An error occurred [com.eviware.soapui.plugins.auto.factories.AutoDiscoveryMethodFactory], see error log for details
Fri Feb 19 11:49:05 CET 2016:ERROR:An error occurred [com.eviware.soapui.plugins.auto.factories.AutoImportMethodFactory], see error log for details
Added AutoFactory for [PluginPrefs]
Added AutoFactory for [PluginPanelBuilder]
Added AutoFactory for [PluginPanelBuilder]
Added AutoFactory for [PluginPanelBuilder]
Added AutoFactory for [PluginTestStep]
Added AutoFactory for [PluginTestStep]
Added AutoFactory for [PluginTestStep]
Fri Feb 19 11:49:06 CET 2016:ERROR:An error occurred [com.eviware.soapui.plugins.auto.factories.AutoDiscoveryMethodFactory], see error log for details
Fri Feb 19 11:49:06 CET 2016:ERROR:An error occurred [com.eviware.soapui.plugins.auto.factories.AutoImportMethodFactory], see error log for details
Fri Feb 19 11:49:06 CET 2016:INFO:Adding plugin from [/Users/jakubriedl/.soapuios/plugins/readyapi-swaggerhub-plugin-1.0.jar]
Fri Feb 19 11:49:06 CET 2016:ERROR:An error occurred [com.eviware.soapui.plugins.auto.factories.AutoDiscoveryMethodFactory], see error log for details
Fri Feb 19 11:49:06 CET 2016:ERROR:An error occurred [com.eviware.soapui.plugins.auto.factories.AutoImportMethodFactory], see error log for details
Fri Feb 19 11:49:06 CET 2016:INFO:4 plugins loaded in 2112 ms
Fri Feb 19 11:49:06 CET 2016:INFO:All plugins loaded
Fri Feb 19 11:49:06 CET 2016:INFO:initialized soapui-settings from [/Users/jakubriedl/soapui-settings.xml]
Fri Feb 19 11:49:07 CET 2016:INFO:Adding plugin from [/Users/jakubriedl/.soapuios/plugins/soapui-swagger-plugin-2.2-dist.jar]
Fri Feb 19 11:49:07 CET 2016:INFO:Adding plugin from [/Users/jakubriedl/.soapuios/plugins/ready-uxm-plugin-1.0.1-dist.jar]
Fri Feb 19 11:49:08 CET 2016:ERROR:An error occurred [com.eviware.soapui.plugins.auto.factories.AutoDiscoveryMethodFactory], see error log for details
Fri Feb 19 11:49:08 CET 2016:ERROR:An error occurred [com.eviware.soapui.plugins.auto.factories.AutoImportMethodFactory], see error log for details
Fri Feb 19 11:49:08 CET 2016:INFO:Adding plugin from [/Users/jakubriedl/.soapuios/plugins/ready-mqtt-plugin-dist.jar]
Fri Feb 19 11:49:08 CET 2016:ERROR:An error occurred [com.eviware.soapui.plugins.auto.factories.AutoDiscoveryMethodFactory], see error log for details
Fri Feb 19 11:49:08 CET 2016:ERROR:An error occurred [com.eviware.soapui.plugins.auto.factories.AutoImportMethodFactory], see error log for details
Added AutoFactory for [PluginPrefs]
Added AutoFactory for [PluginPanelBuilder]
Added AutoFactory for [PluginPanelBuilder]
Added AutoFactory for [PluginPanelBuilder]
Added AutoFactory for [PluginTestStep]
Added AutoFactory for [PluginTestStep]
Added AutoFactory for [PluginTestStep]
Fri Feb 19 11:49:08 CET 2016:ERROR:An error occurred [com.eviware.soapui.plugins.auto.factories.AutoDiscoveryMethodFactory], see error log for details
Fri Feb 19 11:49:08 CET 2016:ERROR:An error occurred [com.eviware.soapui.plugins.auto.factories.AutoImportMethodFactory], see error log for details
Fri Feb 19 11:49:08 CET 2016:INFO:Adding plugin from [/Users/jakubriedl/.soapuios/plugins/readyapi-swaggerhub-plugin-1.0.jar]
Fri Feb 19 11:49:09 CET 2016:ERROR:An error occurred [com.eviware.soapui.plugins.auto.factories.AutoDiscoveryMethodFactory], see error log for details
Fri Feb 19 11:49:09 CET 2016:ERROR:An error occurred [com.eviware.soapui.plugins.auto.factories.AutoImportMethodFactory], see error log for details
Fri Feb 19 11:49:09 CET 2016:INFO:4 plugins loaded in 1529 ms
Fri Feb 19 11:49:09 CET 2016:INFO:All plugins loaded
Fri Feb 19 11:49:09 CET 2016:INFO:Loading workspace from [/Users/jakubriedl/default-soapui-workspace.xml]
Fri Feb 19 11:49:09 CET 2016:INFO:Loaded project from [file:/Users/jakubriedl/Desktop/xsd/A4Res-soapui-project.xml]
Fri Feb 19 11:49:09 CET 2016:INFO:Defaulting to native L&F for Mac OS X
Fri Feb 19 11:49:10 CET 2016:INFO:Used java version: 1.7.0_55
Scheduling garbage collection every 60 seconds
The cajo server is running on localhost:1198/soapuiIntegration
Fri Feb 19 11:49:48 CET 2016:DEBUG:Attempt 1 to execute request
Fri Feb 19 11:49:48 CET 2016:DEBUG:Sending request: POST /terminal HTTP/1.1
Fri Feb 19 11:49:48 CET 2016:DEBUG:I/O error closing connection
   javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkEOF(SSLSocketImpl.java:1476)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkWrite(SSLSocketImpl.java:1488)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:70)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.flushBuffer(AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.java:131)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.flush(AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.java:138)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.LoggingSessionOutputBuffer.flush(LoggingSessionOutputBuffer.java:95)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.doFlush(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:270)
    at org.apache.http.impl.SocketHttpClientConnection.close(SocketHttpClientConnection.java:245)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.close(DefaultClientConnection.java:164)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.close(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:152)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.closeConnection(HttpRequestExecutor.java:142)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:129)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:633)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:454)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.HttpClientSupport$Helper.execute(HttpClientSupport.java:233)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.HttpClientSupport.execute(HttpClientSupport.java:323)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.HttpClientRequestTransport.submitRequest(HttpClientRequestTransport.java:290)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.HttpClientRequestTransport.sendRequest(HttpClientRequestTransport.java:220)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlSubmit.run(WsdlSubmit.java:119)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
   Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1959)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1077)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:702)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:122)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.flushBuffer(AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.java:131)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.flush(AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.java:138)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.LoggingSessionOutputBuffer.flush(LoggingSessionOutputBuffer.java:95)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthOutputStream.flush(ContentLengthOutputStream.java:102)
    at org.apache.http.entity.ByteArrayEntity.writeTo(ByteArrayEntity.java:69)
    at org.apache.http.entity.HttpEntityWrapper.writeTo(HttpEntityWrapper.java:96)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.EntityEnclosingRequestWrapper$EntityWrapper.writeTo(EntityEnclosingRequestWrapper.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.impl.entity.EntitySerializer.serialize(EntitySerializer.java:120)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.sendRequestEntity(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:263)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.sendRequestEntity(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:227)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:255)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpClientSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:123)
    ... 14 more
Fri Feb 19 11:49:48 CET 2016:DEBUG:Closing the connection.
Fri Feb 19 11:49:48 CET 2016:DEBUG:Connection closed
Fri Feb 19 11:49:48 CET 2016:DEBUG:Connection shut down
Fri Feb 19 11:49:48 CET 2016:ERROR:Exception in request: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
Fri Feb 19 11:49:48 CET 2016:ERROR:An error occurred [Received fatal alert: handshake_failure], see error log for details
Fri Feb 19 11:49:49 CET 2016:INFO:Error getting response for [BasicHttpBinding_IPlanky.Login:Request 1]; javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

Comment: Have a look at this https://siking.wordpress.com/2016/02/18/another-way-to-fix-sslhandshakeexception-in-soapui/

Comment: This did not helped. Same error and in SoapUI -> system properties I found java.runtime.version=1.8.0_74-b02 which is up-to-date

Comment: What about http://stackoverflow.com/q/6353849/3124333 ?

Answer (score 0):

The most common cause of a client getting an SSLHandshakeException while calling API Gateway is that the client does not support Server Name Indication (SNI).  API Gateway requires SNI and some older http/https client libraries don't support it.  The latest version of most Java based https clients do support SNI. Try updating your https client library to the latest version.

Comment: Thanks for tip but I have most up-to-date SoapUI (5.2.1) and Java (1.8.0_74)

Comment: @JakubRiedl The library that MikeD is talking about is actually in $SOAPUI_HOME/lib/httpclient-*.jar ... and it is quite outdated. You could try replacing it with the jar from here http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.apache.httpcomponents|httpclient|4.5.1|jar but you would have to replace all the dependencies as well.

Comment: @SiKing it looks like possible way because there is a httpclient-4.1.1.jar. But I'm not familiar with JAVA & maven. Can you please tell me what steps to do to update the library? When I tried to just replace all files listed in dependencies I'm getting lot of errors in log like nullPointerException and so on.

Comment: @JakubRiedl This is **not** an easy procedure, and is **not** guaranteed to give you success. You have to look through the .pom and search for all dependencies that are scope=compile, and replace all of those.

Comment: FYI, SNI support was added in the Apache HTTP client in version 4.3.2: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-1119

Answer (score 0):

Have settings from this thread: [smartbear forum topic for TLS V1.2](https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Open-Source/How-to-enable-TLS-1-2-in-SoapUI/td-p/96239)

And used this specific suggestion added into vmoptions file (soapui bin directory):

```
-Dsoapui.https.protocols=SSLv3,TLSv1.2
```

And have accessed AWS with apikey fine, in soapui v5.3.0

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to SoupUI 5.3.0 resolved the issue for me.