# Handshake_failure exception While executing the client script on a webservice

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, soapui

While executing the the client script on a webservice, I get the `handshake_failure` exception. However, when I try the same via SOAP UI the request is getting response successfully. Can someone please help me out on this?

Error Log:

```
Mar 17, 2016 6:39:23 PM org.apache.cxf.transport.https.SSLUtils getCiphersuites
INFO: The cipher suites have not been configured, falling back to cipher suite filters.
Mar 17, 2016 6:39:23 PM org.apache.cxf.transport.https.SSLUtils getCiphersFromList
INFO: The cipher suites have been set to SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5, TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_NULL_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_NULL_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA, TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_NULL_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_MD5, TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_MD5, TLS_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_MD5, TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_SHA, TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_MD5, TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_SHA, TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5.
Mar 17, 2016 6:39:24 PM org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain doIntercept
INFO: Interceptor has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not send Message.
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:64)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:236)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:471)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:301)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:253)
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:73)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:121)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy38.queryProvider(Unknown Source)
        at client.v2.CarenotesClientV2.processProviderQuery(CarenotesClientV2.java:85)
        at client.PXTestClientV2.findProviderKey(PXTestClientV2.java:395)
        at client.PXTestClientV2.main(PXTestClientV2.java:166)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2011)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1113)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1363)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1391)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1282)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1257)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleHeadersTrustCaching(HTTPConduit.java:1909)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.onFirstWrite(HTTPConduit.java:1864)
        at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractWrappedOutputStream.write(AbstractWrappedOutputStream.java:42)
        at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractThresholdOutputStream.write(AbstractThresholdOutputStream.java:69)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1927)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:66)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:627)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
        ... 10 more

e IS-A: [javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException]
msgObs=
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.OutFaultChainInitiatorObserver@7573e12f
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Could not send Message.
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:141)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy38.queryProvider(Unknown Source)
        at client.v2.CarenotesClientV2.processProviderQuery(CarenotesClientV2.java:85)
        at client.PXTestClientV2.findProviderKey(PXTestClientV2.java:395)
        at client.PXTestClientV2.main(PXTestClientV2.java:166)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2011)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1113)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1363)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1391)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1282)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1257)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleHeadersTrustCaching(HTTPConduit.java:1909)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.onFirstWrite(HTTPConduit.java:1864)
        at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractWrappedOutputStream.write(AbstractWrappedOutputStream.java:42)
        at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractThresholdOutputStream.write(AbstractThresholdOutputStream.java:69)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1927)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:66)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:627)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:236)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:471)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:301)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:253)
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:73)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:121)
```

Comment: This exception are you noticing on server side? Then soapui tag is not relevant.

Comment: The most typical reason for your error is that the certificate server domain for your 3rd party service endpoint is not trusted. You've to add the certificate authority for this cert in your  `cacerts`. Check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353849/received-fatal-alert-handshake-failure-through-sslhandshakeexception) for more insight details.

Comment: @albciff thanks for your input. Missing certificate was the issue.

Comment: @13thGhost nice to help you `:)`