# SSL javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

Tags: java

I'm getting this error while trying to execute and old MapleStory server on linux, I've tried same file on windows and worked without problem. I've tried with serveral Java version without success.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This could be because a root CA's certificate is not present in trust store. For more details refer to [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6353956/6128602).

Comment: I'm using: 
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=filename.keystore -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=passwd -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=filename.keystore -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=passwd