# javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

Tags: java, ssl, weblogic, resttemplate, sslhandshakeexception

I have been trying to connect to a service endpoint which is https. I am using Spring resttemplate, I have added the certificate in keystore of weblogic and java cacerts. I am able to connect to other https Endpoints. but I am getting the HandShake fatal error.

I am getting the following error

org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "path":Received fatal alert: handshake_failure; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

```
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:558)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:503)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:445)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:751)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:341)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:238)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3363)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3333)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2220)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2146)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2124)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1564)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:254)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:295)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:254)
```

Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

```
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1619)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1587)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.recvAlert(SSLEngineImpl.java:1756)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:1060)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:884)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:758)
at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:664)
at weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter.JaSSLEngine$5.run(JaSSLEngine.java:134)
at weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter.JaSSLEngine.doAction(JaSSLEngine.java:732)
at weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter.JaSSLEngine.unwrap(JaSSLEngine.java:132)
at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.unwrap(JSSEFilterImpl.java:603)
at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.unwrapAndHandleResults(JSSEFilterImpl.java:507)
at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.doHandshake(JSSEFilterImpl.java:96)
at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.doHandshake(JSSEFilterImpl.java:75)
at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.write(JSSEFilterImpl.java:448)
at weblogic.socket.JSSESocket$JSSEOutputStream.write(JSSESocket.java:93)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
at java.io.FilterOutputStream.flush(FilterOutputStream.java:140)
at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.writeRequests(HttpURLConnection.java:192)
at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:304)
at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:80)
at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
```

at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:52)at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:542)
    ... 39 more

private String getAuthenticationToken() {

```
        LOGGER.info("Autehenitcation Initiated");
        System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2");
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        String JsonRequest= String.format("{\"userName\":\"%s\",\"password\":\"%s\",\"companyName\":\"%s\"}",user, passwrd, Cname);
        HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(JsonRequest, httpHeaders);
        LOGGER.info("Calling Authenticate Service");
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        try {   
          ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange("https://url", HttpMethod.POST, request, String.class);
          if(response.getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.OK) {
              LOGGER.warn("  Authenticate Service Error");
            return null;
          } 

          else {
              Modelclass model = objectMapper.readValue(response.getBody(), Modelclass.class);
              LOGGER.info("Returning Authentication token");
              return model.AuthenticateResult;
               } 
          }
          catch (Exception ex) {
              ex.printStackTrace();
              LOGGER.warn("Error in Processing Request");
              return null;
        }
```

can anyone help me with this please.

Comment: Does your application has permission to access the resource? Is the source you are trying to access available public? some code would be helpful for us to get better understanding

Comment: Yeah, the resource is available public with the Json request.

Comment: add sine code??

Comment: Added to the question. which is the call I am making to service

Comment: This looks like a classic problem which might be caused by various reasons. Have you looked at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353849/received-fatal-alert-handshake-failure-through-sslhandshakeexception ?