# Java: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

Tags: java

So I am trying to install Adobe Apache flex and getting an error of:

`javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure`

can't seem to find a solution.
I am running latest Java version and using Windows 10 64 bit

Thanks,

Sean

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353849/received-fatal-alert-handshake-failure-through-sslhandshakeexception

Answer (score 0):

this solved my problem:

to download SDK do:

```
1. download: http://flex.apache.org/download-binaries.html and expand to c:\sdk
2. download ant: https://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi and expand to c:\ant
3. For now only seems to work with Java 1.8.0.45 which you can download from here:  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/archive-139210.html  (   http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-javase8-2177648.html#jdk-8u45-oth-JPR ) 
4. Next after you download copy the files from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\lib to  C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_45\lib
5. Next update the securitycrypto extension for 1.8.45 by download http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html and expand to C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_45\lib\security 
6. Next make sure system path includes c:\ant\bin
7. finally ran my command: ant -f installer.xml -Dair.sdk.version=25.0 -Dflash.sdk.version=25.0
```