# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException on the second attempt

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, soap, weblogic

I added the needed certificates to my java/weblogic certs and I got around the SSL Hand shake exception. However once I start my server, the app works fine on the first attempt but when i send a second request, it throws the handshake error again. Is it because of time out or something?

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkEOF(SSLSocketImpl.java:1496)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkWrite(SSLSocketImpl.java:1508)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:70)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at java.io.FilterOutputStream.flush(FilterOutputStream.java:140)

Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts`enter code here`.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1979)
```

Comment: It will be helpful if you post some of your code.

Comment: you may look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353849/received-fatal-alert-handshake-failure-through-sslhandshakeexception

Answer (score 1):

Setting this for JAVA_OPTIONS in the setDomainEnv.cmd solved the problem!

-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2

Comment: Apparently there are two properties: -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2 -Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2