# Coldfusion Webservice errors for complex data types

Tags: web-services, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I'm trying to test the [Bloomberg webservice](https://service.bloomberg.com/assets/dl/dlws.wsdl) for the *getFields* operation but its throwing an error.

> Web service parameter name parameters cannot be found in the provided parameters {CRITERIA}.

Code so far.

```
<cfset FieldSearchCriteria = structNew()>
<cfset FieldSearchCriteria.mnemonic = "NAME">

<cfset GetFieldsRequest = structNew()>
<cfset getFieldsRequest.criteria =  FieldSearchCriteria>



<cfinvoke 
webservice="https://service.bloomberg.com/assets/dl/dlws.wsdl" 
proxyserver="***"
proxyport="***"
proxyuser="***"
proxypassword="***"
method="getFields" 
refreshwsdl="false"
wsVersion="1"
argumentcollection="#getFieldsRequest#"
returnvariable="aTemp"> 

<cfdump var="#aTemp#">
```

Below is the corresponding soapUI request which worked

```
<soapenv:Body>
  <ns:getFieldsRequest>
     <ns:criteria>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <ns:mnemonic>NAME</ns:mnemonic>
     </ns:criteria>
  </ns:getFieldsRequest>
```

Any pointers?

**Update 1:** createobject() worked to an extent with the change in arguments. But now throwing the handshake error.

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

Code:

```
<cfscript>
    ws = createObject("webservice", "https://service.bloomberg.com/assets/dl/dlws.wsdl",{refreshwsdl=true,proxyserver="***",proxyport="***",proxyuser="***",proxypassword="***",wsversion=1});
    //show web service methods for debugging purposes
    //writeDump(ws);

    // construct arguments
    args = {parameters={criteria={mnemonic="NAME"}}
        };

    writeDump(args);
    // call the method
    result  = ws.getFields(argumentCollection=args);

    writeDump(result)
</cfscript>
```

We were given a x.509 .p12 certificate and have encoded to DER using OpenSSL. 
At the moment, not sure if the stored certificate has an issue.

**Final Update:**
Finally, managed to make the webservice run using the cfhttp call instead.
Ben's [blog post](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/1809-making-soap-web-service-requests-with-coldfusion-and-cfhttp.htm) was an excellent guide. I was unable to resolve the certificate issues with the keystore for `cfinvoke`.

```
<cfsavecontent variable="soapBody">
    <soapenv:Envelope
        xxmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
        xmlns:ns="http://services.bloomberg.com/datalicense/dlws/ps/20071001">
        <soapenv:Header/>
        <soapenv:Body>
            <ns:getFieldsRequest>
                <ns:criteria>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <ns:mnemonic>NAME</ns:mnemonic>
                </ns:criteria>
            </ns:getFieldsRequest>
        </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

```
<cfhttp
    url="https://dlws.bloomberg.com/dlps"
    method="post"
    result="httpResponse"
    clientcert="#ExpandPath(".")#\cert.p12"
    clientcertpassword="****">

    <!---
        Most SOAP action require some sort of SOAP Action header
        to be used.
    --->
    <cfhttpparam
        type="header"
        name="SOAPAction"
        value="""getFields"""
        />

    <cfhttpparam
        type="xml"
        value="#trim( soapBody )#"
        />

</cfhttp>

<cfdump var="#XmlParse(httpResponse.filecontent)#">
```

Comment: Any different behavior if you change `refreshwsdl="false"` to `refreshwsdl="true"` ?

Comment: @Miguel-F: Nope, still the same error.

Comment: Using [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6353956/8895292) as guide, I enabled debugging and the logs reported "*Warning: no suitable certificate found - continuing without client authentication*".  I didn't touch the default certificates, so your results may differ. But if you haven't already, try adding `-Djavax.net.debug=all` and check the logs.

Comment: @Ageax : We already have the debug enabled on our test environment and can see the same `warning`. Looks like the converted `der` certificate has an issue.

Comment: @GauravS - Did you check the keystore to verify it was imported under the expected alias? Might also try something like http://keystore-explorer.org/ which is sometimes easier than keytool.exe for getting the big picture.

Comment: @Ageax : Yes, I have tried using the `keystore explorer` as well and constantly getting the `handshake` error. Now trying using the `cfhttp` call.

Comment: Glad you were able to get cfhttp working at least. You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to make the webservice run using the `cfhttp` call instead. Ben's [blog post](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/1809-making-soap-web-service-requests-with-coldfusion-and-cfhttp.htm) was an excellent guide. I was unable to resolve the certificate issues with the keystore for `cfinvoke` method.

```
<cfsavecontent variable="soapBody">
<soapenv:Envelope
    xxmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:ns="http://services.bloomberg.com/datalicense/dlws/ps/20071001">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns:getFieldsRequest>
            <ns:criteria>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <ns:mnemonic>NAME</ns:mnemonic>
            </ns:criteria>
        </ns:getFieldsRequest>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope> 
<cfhttp
url="https://dlws.bloomberg.com/dlps"
method="post"
result="httpResponse"
clientcert="#ExpandPath(".")#\cert.p12"
clientcertpassword="****">

<!---
    Most SOAP action require some sort of SOAP Action header
    to be used.
--->
<cfhttpparam
    type="header"
    name="SOAPAction"
    value="""getFields""" <!--- Note : extra pair of quotes are required --->
    />

<cfhttpparam
    type="xml"
    value="#trim( soapBody )#"
    />
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using createObject() and invoking the getFields() method instead. It seemed to get past the "cannot find parameter error".

```
<cfset svc = createObject("webservice"
                , "https://service.bloomberg.com/assets/dl/dlws.wsdl"
                , {wsVersion=1}
            )>
<cfset getFieldsRequest = {criteria={mnemonic="NAME"}}>
<cfset result = svc.getFields(getFieldsRequest)>
<cfdump var="#result#">
```

(Nothing to do with the issue, but CF11 supports the shortcut syntax for structures, i.e. `{}`)

Comment: I had been testing with the `createobject()` today and found `args = {parameters={criteria={mnemonic="NAME"}}
        };
    
    writeDump(args);
    // call the method
    result  = ws.getFields(argumentCollection=args);` worked to an extent but now throwing the webservice handshake error. `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure`. Having a look at the certificate in the keystore now.

Comment: Yeah, the createObject syntax only helps with the method signature problem. Certificates are a different ball of wax.