# Codfusion keystore : Handshake errors for DER encoded certificate

Tags: ssl, coldfusion, ssl-certificate, soapui, coldfusion-11

Following up from [previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55233591/coldfusion-webservice-errors-for-complex-data-types) asked question.

We were provided with an x.509 v3 .pkcs12 certificate from Bloomberg.

For testing the webservice on Coldfusion, the certificate had to be encoded to DER for  installing in the keystore.

I managed to install the certificate successfully using the [link](https://coldfusion.adobe.com/2018/10/installing-an-ssl-certificate-into-coldfusions-trust-store/).
But getting the following error when calling the webservice.

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

Testing the same(.der) certificate on SoapUI threw the below error.

> ERROR:java.security.KeyStoreException: failed to extract any certificates or private keys - maybe bad password?

Note: The provided .p12 and the converted .pem certificates work as expected on SoapUI.

Any pointers?