# Handshake_failure without SSLContext in java HTTPclient

Tags: java, ssl, jsse

I felt to have faced a strange problem, I wrote a core java http client without an SSLContext and when I run the program to call REST service, it started failing with the below exception. However when i added SSLContext to the client it passed and I see response.

```
Initial Code without SSLContext :
String url = "https://URL";
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();     
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");           
    con.setRequestProperty("CONTENT-TYPE", "application/json"); 
    String request = "{ json Request }";    
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
    wr.write(request.getBytes());
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();
    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
```

Exception :
        javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

```
During SSL debugging it is found that client server sends TSLv1.2 during ClientHello, however i dont see a ServerHello in return.
But when the below SSL code error disappeared

SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2"); 
        sc.init(null, null, new java.security.SecureRandom());
        con.setSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
```

Help me understand what happens if I don't set SSLContext and the behavior when SSLContext is added.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Received fatal alert: handshake\_failure through SSLHandshakeException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353849/received-fatal-alert-handshake-failure-through-sslhandshakeexception)

Comment: Specifically, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39751506/207421).