# Keep getting error calling XML webservice from SoapUI

Tags: xml, web-services, ssl, soap, soapui

I'm trying to call a webservice from SoapUI 5.6 with an JKS keystore. I'm new to XML and have only worked with JSON before.

I've created a project in SoapUI 5.6 from a WSDL and I've loaded a keystore into SoapUI with the correct password.

I get an SSLHandshakeError.

I read up on this and found that I needed to add this to vmoptions, which I did:

-Dsoapui.https.protocols=SSLv3,TLSv1.2

I tried both, and each of SSLv3 and TLSv1.2 by themselves. Same result.

Here are the logs:

SoapUI log:

```
Mon Nov 29 16:19:09 CET 2021:DEBUG:Attempt 1 to execute request
Mon Nov 29 16:19:09 CET 2021:DEBUG:Sending request: POST /services/XMLProdukt HTTP/1.1
Mon Nov 29 16:19:09 CET 2021:DEBUG:I/O error closing connection
   java.net.SocketException: Connection or outbound has closed
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppOutputStream.write(SSLSocketImpl.java:1004)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.flushBuffer(AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.java:160)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.flush(AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.java:168)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.LoggingSessionOutputBuffer.flush(LoggingSessionOutputBuffer.java:99)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.doFlush(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:273)
    at org.apache.http.impl.SocketHttpClientConnection.close(SocketHttpClientConnection.java:243)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.close(DefaultClientConnection.java:178)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.close(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:170)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.closeConnection(HttpRequestExecutor.java:142)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:129)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:684)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:486)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.HttpClientSupport$Helper.execute(HttpClientSupport.java:233)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.HttpClientSupport.execute(HttpClientSupport.java:323)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.HttpClientRequestTransport.submitRequest(HttpClientRequestTransport.java:301)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.HttpClientRequestTransport.sendRequest(HttpClientRequestTransport.java:231)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlSubmit.run(WsdlSubmit.java:119)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
Mon Nov 29 16:19:09 CET 2021:DEBUG:Closing the connection.
Mon Nov 29 16:19:09 CET 2021:DEBUG:Connection 0.0.0.0:49229<->194.14.186.30:443 closed
Mon Nov 29 16:19:09 CET 2021:DEBUG:Connection 0.0.0.0:49229<->194.14.186.30:443 shut down
Mon Nov 29 16:19:09 CET 2021:DEBUG:Connection 0.0.0.0:49229<->194.14.186.30:443 closed
Mon Nov 29 16:19:09 CET 2021:ERROR:Exception in request: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
Mon Nov 29 16:19:09 CET 2021:ERROR:An error occurred [Received fatal alert: handshake_failure], see error log for details
Mon Nov 29 16:19:09 CET 2021:INFO:Error getting response for [XMLProduktSoapBinding.getProdukt:Request 1]; javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

Error log:

```
Mon Nov 29 16:19:09 CET 2021:ERROR:javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received      fatal alert: handshake_failure
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:307)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert$AlertConsumer.consume(Alert.java:285)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:180)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:164)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1180)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1091)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:402)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.ensureNegotiated(SSLSocketImpl.java:721)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppOutputStream.write(SSLSocketImpl.java:998)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.flushBuffer(AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.java:160)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.write(AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.java:182)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.LoggingSessionOutputBuffer.write(LoggingSessionOutputBuffer.java:75)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthOutputStream.write(ContentLengthOutputStream.java:113)
    at org.apache.http.entity.ByteArrayEntity.writeTo(ByteArrayEntity.java:114)
    at org.apache.http.entity.HttpEntityWrapper.writeTo(HttpEntityWrapper.java:94)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.EntityEnclosingRequestWrapper$EntityWrapper.writeTo(EntityEnclosingRequestWrapper.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.entity.EntitySerializer.serialize(EntitySerializer.java:118)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.sendRequestEntity(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:266)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.sendRequestEntity(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:239)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:238)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpClientSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:123)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:684)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:486)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.HttpClientSupport$Helper.execute(HttpClientSupport.java:233)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.HttpClientSupport.execute(HttpClientSupport.java:323)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.HttpClientRequestTransport.submitRequest(HttpClientRequestTransport.java:301)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.HttpClientRequestTransport.sendRequest(HttpClientRequestTransport.java:231)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlSubmit.run(WsdlSubmit.java:119)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
```

Anyone got any idea? I'm new to XML and I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: This has nothing to do with XML. This is a problem with the two machines talking to each other over SSL. Going through [all this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6353956/3124333) helped me when I was facing similar issue.

Comment: What could be the issue...? I use the certificate that was handed to the company I worked for, with the correct password. The service I'm calling is a huge public service I know works and I use their WSDL. Seems like nothing could be wrong..??

Comment: **Where** did you install the certificate? SoapUI, by default, uses it's own Java, which has it's own Certificate Store. Have a look at this https://siking.wordpress.com/2016/02/18/another-way-to-fix-sslhandshakeexception-in-soapui/