# SSL handshake failure while connecting to Database

Tags: java, ssl, jdbc, aix, oracle

I am getting SSK handshake failure error when connecting Database using certificates from java jdbc programme.
I have the correct client certificates and all getting matched with server .
I am also getting the *** Finished  message.But after that getting handshake failure.
I am using AIX 6.1, IBM JRE 1.8 in client machine and DB is Oracle 19c
Can anyone help here.

```
main, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
main, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
main, fatal: engine already closed.  Rethrowing javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
main, fatal: engine already closed.  Rethrowing javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
main, called closeOutbound()
main, closeOutboundInternal()
main, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  warning, description = close_notify
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
[Raw write]: length = 7
```

Comment: [Tips on debugging a handshake failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353849/received-fatal-alert-handshake-failure-through-sslhandshakeexception). If this is an incompatibility between the server and client, Oracle 19c is ~2019, JRE 1.8 is potentially old, which version of it are you using? (if it's not recent, you could try upgrading that)

Comment: @teapot418 - I don't have the option to upgrade JRE. is there anyway to have any workaround?

Comment: You can try the tip about JCE in the above link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade jre resolved the issue .
The problem was with the JRE and this would never show clearly in the logs. If you face similar errors try with an upgraded JRE and check.

Comment: Please elaborate how you could fix your issue.