# CIRCULAR REFERENCE: org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, java-21

We are using Spring Boot 3.2.2 and spring-webflux, and the WebClient for Restcalls.

And get this error, CIRCULAR REFERENCE: org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure.

What is the reason, how to solve it? Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Daniel Förberg

```
@Value("${api.any.curity.admin.base-uri}")
private String adminBaseUrl;

@Bean(name = "curityAdminWebClient")
@Profile("!local")
public WebClient curityAdminWebClient() {
    return WebClient.builder().baseUrl(adminBaseUrl).build();
}
```

This is the setup. What do we need to change? Sounds like a certificate issue in curity. But works with curl. Might be webclient is more restrictive.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Received fatal alert: handshake\_failure through SSLHandshakeException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353849/received-fatal-alert-handshake-failure-through-sslhandshakeexception)