ORA-29532: Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
I am getting ORA-29532: Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure exception when I try to run java class from PL SQL. Some URL works fine, but most get this error.
When I run this class from IntelliJ every kind of URL works fine. Can anyone please direct me where the problem could be?
CREATE OR REPLACE AND COMPILE JAVA SOURCE NAMED "ConnectHttps" AS   
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

public class ConnectHttps
{
    public static String GetHttps() throws IOException {
        URL u = new URL("https://api.blockchain.com/v3/exchange/l2/BTC-USD"); // - doesnt work
        //URL u = new URL("https://official-joke-api.appspot.com/random_joke"); // - work
        HttpsURLConnection http = (HttpsURLConnection) u.openConnection();
        http.setAllowUserInteraction(true);
        http.setRequestMethod("GET");
        http.connect();

        InputStream is = http.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
};

/
> create or replace function test return varchar2
> AS LANGUAGE JAVA
> NAME 'ConnectHttps.GetHttps() return java.lang.String';

/
> exec dbms_output.put_line(test);


Looks to me that you need to add the relevant certificate to Oracle's embedded JVM.

Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/6353849/1509264 (and the Oracle JVM will be different to the JVM used by IntelliJ so if you have updated the trust store to trust the server's CA certificate in IntelliJ then it will not have been trusted in Oracle's JVM trust store; similarly the JVMs do not necessarily support the same cypher suites, etc.).

The correct way would be to place the trusted root CA in a separate JavaKeystore file and load it into a Trustmanager as trusted root CA certificates. That way it doesn't matter which JRE/JDK you use.
